# Why does reading a record struct fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, iostream

Suppose we have the following situation:

- A record struct is declared as follows

  ```
  struct Person {
      unsigned int id;
      std::string name;
      uint8_t age;
      // ...
  };
  ```
- Records are stored in a file using the following format:

  ```
  ID      Forename Lastname Age
  ------------------------------
  1267867 John     Smith    32
  67545   Jane     Doe      36
  8677453 Gwyneth  Miller   56
  75543   J. Ross  Unusual  23
  ...
  ```

The file should be read in to collect an arbitrary number of the `Person` records mentioned above:

```
std::istream& ifs = std::ifstream("SampleInput.txt");
std::vector<Person> persons;

Person actRecord;
while(ifs >> actRecord.id >> actRecord.name >> actRecord.age) {
    persons.push_back(actRecord);
}

if(!ifs) {
    std::err << "Input format error!" << std::endl;
}
```

**Question:**
What can I do to read in the separate values storing their values into the one `actRecord` variables' fields?

The above [code sample](http://ideone.com/TosCsl) ends up with run time errors:

```
Runtime error    time: 0 memory: 3476 signal:-1
stderr: Input format error!
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think it is relevant. I'll add the [tag:c++11] tag also, to open a broader field of solutions. As mentioned, the original question may also narrow too much. Feel free to touch it ;) ...

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet so as to handle multiple spaces for names, because I think I have a good way to handle this.

Comment: @Veritas If you have another good solution, feel free to add another answer here. This post is meant as a canonical Q&A.

Comment: Did you try to do operator overloading?

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı _'Did you try to do operator overloading?'_ Yes, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23070803/1413395).

Comment: Your terminology is off. What is a "struct record field"? A "record struct"?

Answer (score 4):

You have whitespace between firstname and lastname.  Change your class to have firstname and lastname as separate strings and it should work.  The other thing you can do is to read in two separate variables such as `name1` and `name2` and assign it as

```
actRecord.name = name1 + " " + name2;
```

Comment: I don't want to have separate strings for _forename_ and _lastname_. Note this question is meant to be a canonical of a frequently asked problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The problem is that the input operator `>>` separates on whitespace. You can't read a string containing whitespace with the input operator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The simplest solution may be to reorder the file contents so the name is last, then you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get the name: `std::ifs >> actRecord.id >> actRecord.age && std::getline(ifs, actRecord.name)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hmm, I like the proposal deviating for temporary variables. Though I'm still wondering how names containing more space separated parts could be handled, without placing the name at the end of the record info.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Let each record take multiple lines, with one line per data field? Maybe a tagged file format (like XML/JSON or just a simple home-made keyword-data format)? As long as you have space-separated data in the file, you need special solutions. It's only going to be worse if you have multiple text fields that allows space.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Then the answer is **No** (you can't do anything without more format restrctions)?? Would be acceptable, for what I meant to ask, to refer in future ;) ...

Comment: @unxnut I'm afraid that, compared to the other answers provided, your statement is true (but was ever clear when asking), but doesn't really provide a general solution. (Thus I retracted my upvote)

Answer (score 4):

One [viable solution](http://ideone.com/Svbg0y) is to reorder input fields (if this is possible)

```
ID      Age Forename Lastname
1267867 32  John     Smith    
67545   36  Jane     Doe      
8677453 56  Gwyneth  Miller   
75543   23  J. Ross  Unusual  
...
```

and read in the records as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    uint8_t age;
    // ...
};

int main() {
    std::istream& ifs = std::cin; // Open file alternatively
    std::vector<Person> persons;

    Person actRecord;
    unsigned int age;
    while(ifs >> actRecord.id >> age && 
          std::getline(ifs, actRecord.name)) {
        actRecord.age = uint8_t(age);
        persons.push_back(actRecord);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cheap solution but this is the most straightforward way to go about things if we are allowed to reorder the input fields. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of a manipulator I came up with that counts the delimiter through each extracted character. Using the number of delimiters you specify, it will extract words from the input stream. Here's a working demo.

```c++
template<class charT>
struct word_inserter_impl {
    word_inserter_impl(std::size_t words, std::basic_string<charT>& str, charT delim)
        : str_(str)
        , delim_(delim)
        , words_(words)
    { }

    friend std::basic_istream<charT>&
    operator>>(std::basic_istream<charT>& is, const word_inserter_impl<charT>& wi) {
        typename std::basic_istream<charT>::sentry ok(is);

        if (ok) {
            std::istreambuf_iterator<charT> it(is), end;
            std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> dest(wi.str_);

            while (it != end && wi.words_) {
                if (*it == wi.delim_ && --wi.words_ == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                dest++ = *it++;
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
private:
    std::basic_string<charT>& str_;
    charT delim_;
    mutable std::size_t words_;
};

template<class charT=char>
word_inserter_impl<charT> word_inserter(std::size_t words, std::basic_string<charT>& str, charT delim = charT(' ')) {
    return word_inserter_impl<charT>(words, str, delim);
}
```

Now you can just do:

```c++
while (ifs >> actRecord.id >> word_inserter(2, actRecord.name) >> actRecord.age) {
    std::cout << actRecord.id << " " << actRecord.name << " " << actRecord.age << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8352941f77df8ac2)

Comment: I had at least a similar idea, to specify an additional field delimiter character, instead of specifying the possible number of parts statically(?!?).

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to read in the first entry into an `ID` variable.
Then read in all the other words from the line (just push them in a temporary vector) and construct the name of the individual with all the elements, except the last entry which is the Age.

This would allow you to still have the Age on the last position but be able to deal with name like "J. Ross Unusual".

**Update** to add some code which illustrates the theory above:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    std::fstream ifs("in.txt");
    std::vector<Person> persons;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ifs, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        // first: ID simply read it
        Person actRecord;
        iss >> actRecord.id;

        // next iteration: read in everything
        std::string temp;
        std::vector<std::string> tempvect;
        while(iss >> temp) {
            tempvect.push_back(temp);
        }

        // then: the name, let's join the vector in a way to not to get a trailing space
        // also taking care of people who do not have two names ...
        int LAST = 2;
        if(tempvect.size() < 2) // only the name and age are in there
        {
            LAST = 1;
        }
        std::ostringstream oss;
        std::copy(tempvect.begin(), tempvect.end() - LAST,
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(oss, " "));
        // the last element
        oss << *(tempvect.end() - LAST);
        actRecord.name = oss.str();

        // and the age
        actRecord.age = std::stoi( *(tempvect.end() - 1) );
        persons.push_back(actRecord);
    }

    for(std::vector<Person>::const_iterator it = persons.begin(); it != persons.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it->id << ":" << it->name << ":" << it->age << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we can easily split a line on whitespace and we know that the only value that can be separated is the name, a possible solution is to use a deque for each line containing the whitespace separated elements of the line. The id and the age can easily be retrieved from the deque and the remaining elements can be concatenated to retrieve the name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

struct Person {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    uint8_t age;
};
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::ifstream ifs("SampleInput.txt");
    std::vector<Person> records;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ifs,line)) {

        std::istringstream ss(line);

        std::deque<std::string> info(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), {});

        Person record;
        record.id = std::stoi(info.front()); info.pop_front();
        record.age = std::stoi(info.back()); info.pop_back();

        std::ostringstream name;
        std::copy
            ( info.begin()
            , info.end()
            , std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(name," "));
        record.name = name.str(); record.name.pop_back();

        records.push_back(std::move(record));
    }

    for (auto& record : records) {
        std::cout << record.id << " " << record.name << " " 
                  << static_cast<unsigned int>(record.age) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THX for supporting this Q&A. Your answer provides a good solution, without the need to introduce additional delimiting characters for a string. Though, similar as the straightforward answer to put the complete name at the end of the record, it's matching an edge case, that works for the particular input format given in the question.

Comment: What I like about this is that sometimes you don't have any control over the input file - In my case my code is called by a web service with data recieved in a particular format.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to read in the separate words forming the name into the one `actRecord.name` variable?

The general answer is: **No**, you can't do this without additional delimiter specifications and exceptional parsing for the parts forming the intended `actRecord.name` contents.
This is because a `std::string` field will be parsed just up to the next occurence of a whitespace character.

It's **noteworthy** that some standard formats (like e.g. `.csv`) may require to support distinguishing blanks (`' '`) from tab (`'\t'`) or other characters, to delimit certain record fields (which may not be visible at a first glance).

**Also note:**
To read an `uint8_t` value as numeric input, you'll have to deviate using a temporary `unsigned int`value. Reading just a `unsigned char` (aka `uint8_t`) will screw up the stream parsing state.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to require certain delimiter characters for a particular field, and provide a special extraction manipulator for this purpose.

Let's suppose we define the delimiter character `"`, and the input should look  like this:

```
1267867 "John Smith"      32   
67545   "Jane Doe"        36  
8677453 "Gwyneth Miller"  56  
75543   "J. Ross Unusual" 23
```

Generally needed includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
```

The record declaration:

```
struct Person {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    uint8_t age;
    // ...
};
```

Declaration/definition of a proxy class (struct) that supports being used with the `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const delim_field_extractor_proxy&)` global operator overload:

```
struct delim_field_extractor_proxy { 
    delim_field_extractor_proxy
       ( std::string& field_ref
       , char delim = '"'
       ) 
    : field_ref_(field_ref), delim_(delim) {}

    friend 
    std::istream& operator>>
       ( std::istream& is
       , const delim_field_extractor_proxy& extractor_proxy);

    void extract_value(std::istream& is) const {
        field_ref_.clear();
        char input;
        bool addChars = false;
        while(is) {
            is.get(input);
            if(is.eof()) {
                break;
            }
            if(input == delim_) {
                addChars = !addChars;
                if(!addChars) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(addChars) {
                field_ref_ += input;
            }
        }
        // consume whitespaces
        while(std::isspace(is.peek())) {
            is.get();
        }
    }
    std::string& field_ref_;
    char delim_;
};
```

---

```
std::istream& operator>>
    ( std::istream& is
    , const delim_field_extractor_proxy& extractor_proxy) {
    extractor_proxy.extract_value(is);
    return is;
}
```

Plumbing everything connected together and instantiating the `delim_field_extractor_proxy`:

```
int main() {
    std::istream& ifs = std::cin; // Open file alternatively
    std::vector<Person> persons;

    Person actRecord;
    int act_age;
    while(ifs >> actRecord.id 
              >> delim_field_extractor_proxy(actRecord.name,'"')
              >> act_age) {
        actRecord.age = uint8_t(act_age);
        persons.push_back(actRecord);
    }

    for(auto it = persons.begin();
        it != persons.end();
        ++it) {
        std::cout << it->id << ", " 
                      << it->name << ", " 
                      << int(it->age) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [working example here](http://ideone.com/tvi7Io).

**NOTE:**
This solution also [works well](http://ideone.com/ZwEARz) specifying a TAB character (`\t`) as delimiter, which is useful parsing standard `.csv` formats.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt at solving the parsing problem.

```
int main()
{
   std::ifstream ifs("test-115.in");
   std::vector<Person> persons;

   while (true)
   {
      Person actRecord;
      // Read the ID and the first part of the name.
      if ( !(ifs >> actRecord.id >> actRecord.name ) )
      {
         break;
      }

      // Read the rest of the line.
      std::string line;
      std::getline(ifs,line);

      // Pickup the rest of the name from the rest of the line.
      // The last token in the rest of the line is the age.
      // All other tokens are part of the name.
      // The tokens can be separated by ' ' or '\t'.
      size_t pos = 0;
      size_t iter1 = 0;
      size_t iter2 = 0;
      while ( (iter1 = line.find(' ', pos)) != std::string::npos ||
              (iter2 = line.find('\t', pos)) != std::string::npos )
      {
         size_t iter = (iter1 != std::string::npos) ? iter1 : iter2;
         actRecord.name += line.substr(pos, (iter - pos + 1));
         pos = iter + 1;

         // Skip multiple whitespace characters.
         while ( isspace(line[pos]) )
         {
            ++pos;
         }
      }

      // Trim the last whitespace from the name.
      actRecord.name.erase(actRecord.name.size()-1);

      // Extract the age.
      // std::stoi returns an integer. We are assuming that
      // it will be small enough to fit into an uint8_t.
      actRecord.age = std::stoi(line.substr(pos).c_str());

      // Debugging aid.. Make sure we have extracted the data correctly.
      std::cout << "ID: " << actRecord.id
         << ", name: " << actRecord.name
         << ", age: " << (int)actRecord.age << std::endl;
      persons.push_back(actRecord);
   }

   // If came here before the EOF was reached, there was an
   // error in the input file.
   if ( !(ifs.eof()) ) {
       std::cerr << "Input format error!" << std::endl;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When seeing such an input file, I think it is not a (new way) delimited file, but a good old fixed size fields one, like Fortran and Cobol programmers used to deal with. So I would parse it like that (note I separated forename and lastname) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string forename;
    std::string lastname;
    uint8_t age;
    // ...
};

int main() {
    std::istream& ifs = std::ifstream("file.txt");
    std::vector<Person> persons;
    std::string line;
    int fieldsize[] = {8, 9, 9, 4};

    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) {
        Person person;
        int field = 0, start=0, last;
        std::stringstream fieldtxt;
        fieldtxt.str(line.substr(start, fieldsize[0]));
        fieldtxt >> person.id;
        start += fieldsize[0];
        person.forename=line.substr(start, fieldsize[1]);
        last = person.forename.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1;
        person.forename.erase(last);
        start += fieldsize[1];
        person.lastname=line.substr(start, fieldsize[2]);
        last = person.lastname.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1;
        person.lastname.erase(last);
        start += fieldsize[2];
        std::string a = line.substr(start, fieldsize[3]);
        fieldtxt.str(line.substr(start, fieldsize[3]));
        fieldtxt >> age;
        person.age = person.age;
        persons.push_back(person);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I didn't mention explicitly that the fields are fixed size (and didn't actually think in this direction, when I wrote the question), but you're right my sample actually looks like fixed size format.