# taking strings with whitespaces in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string p;
int n,i;
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cin>>p;
    cout<<p<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

hiii..
i wanna take two strings and then print them one by one as in prog. but when i take n=2 and input the string  "I wanna go"
it gives the output :

```
i
wanna
```

and it didn't ask me for second string.it is taking the string until it gets a whitespace.what should i do to resolve this?

Comment: Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: The for loop will repeat twice. std::cin reads input until the white space. If you want the entire line, use std::getline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces

Check the std::getline answer over there.

Comment: A related, more generalized Q&A article about input of whitespace separated strings: [**Why does reading a struct record fields from file fail, and how can I fix it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-file-fail-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the initial value of your iteration variable i in you for statement to the following one:

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
```

Comment: u r right but i m not getting why to do so...will u please tell me the reason?

Comment: @user3537331 sure thing. Give me please a few minutes.

Comment: Your loop runs WHILE it is LESS THAN or EQUAL TO n. Your loop runs once where i = 1, and again where i = 2. Once i = 3, the loop stops running. Changing i to initially = 0 means it runs thrice. Once where i = 0, once where i = 1, and once again where i = 2.

Comment: @user3537331 I din't make it to answer you before Ben. Ben explains as I would. Thanks Ben !

Comment: ya sir u r absolutely right. but when i take n=2, for loop should run twice.. one for i=1, and then for i=2 as 2<=2 is true so it should take 2 strings but it is taking just one and then terminates...... why so?

Comment: @user3537331 What happens there is that actually when you write for instance I wanna go it and the press enter considers it as three strings and for that reason it prints one word after the other in a newline and terminates. These are three words 1) I, 2) wanna and 3) go. So if you start with i=1 and i<=2 and you type I wanna go and then enter it will print you only the first two words in the string. You can check it actually this if you insert one word then enter then insert the other then enter and so on. If it doesn't make sense this please let me know what is ambiguous. Thanks

Comment: ohh ... i think u got it wrong...it is taking only one string when i have used std::string p   ... etc. and the problem of whitespaces has been solved... i will also search for this...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using std::getline.

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

The above example is summarized from:
[std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: thanx.. its working but when i m taking n=4 it is taking only 3 strings why so?

Comment: try this `for(int n=0; n<4; n++){ std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s); std::cout < s << std::endl; }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `operator >>` you should use function `std::getline`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
   int n;

   std::cin >> n;

   std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
   // or simply std::cin.ignore();

   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
   {
      std::string p;
      std::getline( std::cin, p );
      std::cout << p << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```