# How do i input strings with spaces?

Tags: c++

I want to input a string (with spaces in between) and i am using cin.getline(). But i am getting a run time error (loop executes infinitely).

```
class account
{
        int acno;
        int password;
        char name[50];
        char address[100];
        char sex;
        string phonenumber;
    public:
        void create_account();  //function to get data from user
        void show_account() const;  //function to show data on screen
        void modify();  //function to add new data
        void withdraw(int,int); //function to accept amount and subtract from balance amount
        void donate(int,int);   //function to accept amount and add to balance amount
        void report() const;    //function to show data in tabular format
        int retacno() const;    //function to return account number
        int retpassword() const;    //function to return password
};  // class definition
```

this is my function for inputting the data for a class record.

```
void account::create_account()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter The account No. :";
    cin>>acno;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Name of The account Holder : ";
    cin.getline(name,49);
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\n\nEnter your Password (Max 8 characters) : ";
    cin>>password;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\n\nEnter your Address : ";
    cin.getline(address,99);
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\nEnter your Contact Number: ";
    cin>>phonenumber;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\nSex (Enter M for male and F for female): ";
    cin>>sex;
    cout<<"\n\n\nAccount Created..\n\n";
}
```

When I execute this I get a run time error if I introduce spaces in between string entries
and it skips the string input if I don't use cin.ignore() function.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: If you need to input a string with spaces into a char array (as in your example), you can use "fgets" function. 
But, it's better to use `std::string` class instead of char arrays and input string using "getline" function that takes 2 parameters: input stream and input string. E.g. `getline( cin, str );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the free-standing `std::getline` function, **not** the member function. The former operates on a `std::string`, so you don't have to mess around with a raw pointer.