# A real solution to the 'cin' and 'getline' issue

Tags: c++, cin, getline

How do I get rid of the leading ' ' and '\n' symbols when I'm not sure I'll get a cin, before the getline?

Example:

```
int a;
char s[1001];
if(rand() == 1){
    cin >> a;
}

cin.getline(s);
```

If I put a cin.ignore() before the getline, I may lose the first symbol of the string, so is my only option to put it after every use of 'cin >>' ? Because that's not very efficient way to do it when you are working on a big project.

Is there a better way than this:

```
int a;
string s;

if(rand() == 1){
    cin >> a;
}

do getline(cin, s); while(s == "");
```

Comment: Not sure without seeing your exact input, but may be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: Don't mix `>>` and `getline`. Just always use `getline`. As it stands your code is broken anyway since you don't check whether `cin >> a` succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::string line, maybe_an_int;

if (rand() == 1)
{
    if (!(std::getline(std::cin, maybe_an_int))
    {
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

if (!(std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int a = std::stoi(maybe_an_int);    // this may throw an exception
```

You can parse the string `maybe_an_int` in several different ways. You could also use `std::strtol`, or a string stream (under the same condition as the first `if` block):

```
    std::istringstream iss(maybe_an_int);
    int a;
    if (!(iss >> a >> std::ws) || iss.get() != EOF)
    {
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

You could of course handle parsing errors more gracefully, e.g. by running the entire thing in a loop until the user inputs valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Both the space character and the newline character are classified as whitespace by standard IOStreams. If you are mixing formatted I/O with unformatted I/O and you need to clear the stream of residual whitespace, use the [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) manipulator:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s) {

}
```