# Four variable file I/O C++ into hash table for processing

Tags: c++, file, io, hashtable

I have a problem with C++ File input.
I have a file with **n** lines that each lines contains 4 variables. I need them read them into a hash table that I created. My problem is that I can't read the file correct way.
For example here the input file variables:

```
line id cont uniq-number Band
   0 10  B   02020213456 DaftPunk
   1 11  A   02030213456 Dazy
    and so on..
```

The main problem is to read each variable in line until file EOF.
So I need read in each line these variables id, cout, uniq-number and band and while it is reading put these data inside a hash table to process them even further in C++.
Example

```
cout << "File" << endl;
int date,id;
string group,line,ch;
datar d;
hasher h1;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("file.txt");
while (getline (inFile,line))
{
 // "reads" file each variable   
 inFile >> id >> ch >> date >> group;
 //add these variable in line one to first hash line
 d.id = id;
 d.data = ch;
 d.date= date;
 d.group = group;
 h1.add(d);
//must repeat until file EOF for each line
}
inFile.close();
```

Comment: [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: present a complete example that readers can compile and try out. explain what you're expecting and how the actual behavior differs.

Comment: The link I gave you contains all the information necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: code, that's good. still missing: (1) definition of type `hasher`, (2) what does or does not happen.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i here is table that i am experimenting https://gist.github.com/kilis/5514e0e0d079b479a1af

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i will try it

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: in your linked to question (nice one btw) you have accepted an answer, "No, you can't do this", that is incorrect. there's no problem reading fixed column width data. also, i think it's not completely relevant because there's no hash table.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i know that i can but when i tried all the time my ideas where incorrect. Some kind of error that i coldnt track.

Comment: ok, `hasher` is a type you have defined yourself. but what is it that happens or does not happen when you run the program? what does "i can't read the file correct way" ***mean***?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i tried many versions to read these variables. for example. Read each line then separeting them. also i had a version to use repeated reading each line while eof then some how the count was wrong and data input into hash table was wrong. some wrong variables was in wrong place there

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You are probably right, that I shouldn't have an accepted answer there. And yeah, hash tables aren't mentioned there.

Comment: @kilis: "some wrong variables was in wrong place there", ah! finally. well your current code is *not resilient* against incorrect data. if a name has a space (as πάντα ῥεῖ has hinted strongly about), e.g. "Daft Punk" instead of "DaftPunk" as in your example data, then the reading will get out of synch, or if a line otherwise has too few or too many items, the same happens. one solution for the space-in-name in your case is to use `getline` to read the name, which is ok since the name is last on each line.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf all band names in the data file aren't separated with space, but some variables like id and band names can be shorter and longer and date varible is constant 11 characters and count one char A or B

Answer (score 0):

In this code,

```
while (getline (inFile,line))
{
 // "reads" file each variable   
 inFile >> id >> ch >> date >> group;
 //add these variable in line one to first hash line
 d.id = id;
 d.data = ch;
 d.date= date;
 d.group = group;
 h1.add(d);
//must repeat until file EOF for each line
}
```

the `getline` reads a line.

Then the loop body reads items from the next line.

Instead of that

```
inFile >> id >> ch >> date >> group;
```

do e.g.

```
istringstream linestream( line );
linestream >> id >> ch >> date;
getline( linestream, group );
```

The last `getline` in order to handle possible spaces in a name.

This assumes that the name is last on the line, as it currently is, and it assumes that it's not the case that every second line should be ignored (i.e., that that was bug).

---

It's also a good idea to add *failure checking*.

If a stream operation fails then the stream enters a failure state, and you can check that via the member function `.fail()`.

Comment: Almost but some how buggy http://images.devs-on.net/Image/bElXxTVCWfSFShXk-Region.png

Comment: @kilis Both ABBA and U2, shown in [the image you link to](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/bElXxTVCWfSFShXk-Region.png), have created some awesome music, but are frowned on and even made subjects of jokes by wannabe music aficionados. In the case of U2 I think the bad reputation originated with two really bad albums. In the case of ABBA, probably because of their truly Swedish Pop style. Other than using two such controversial bands, however, I fail to see what's wrong with the presentation. I'm sure you're right, that there's a problem, but what is it?

Comment: its the example file that it reads date and band gets out of sync starting with line 3

Comment: huh? it looks okay to me.

Comment: @kilis: that's not sufficiently concrete to help. sorry.