# Is there a better way to read into multiple variables?

Tags: c++

I have a class that has a lot of string variables:

```
struct Person
{
    string name, dob, state, best_friend, /* etc... */;
};
```

And I have to do this inside my istream operator:

```
getline(cin, p.name);
getline(cin, p.dob);
getline(cin, p.state);
getline(cin, p.best_friend);
...
```

And I have to do this over and over again for all other member variables I have. My question is is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you're getting those from the console?

Comment: Well, you write a function that does that for all of the members of a `Person` (rather than members of the instance `p`), and reuse it... but there is no generic way of telling the compiler that you want to write the stream operators (yet)

Comment: @user2030677 - How many of these member variables are there?

Comment: So you might want to offer the user to enter all this information in a single line. May be related, and worth a look for you: [**Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the following helper function useful:

```c++
static int delimiter() { static int idx(std::ios_base::xalloc()); return idx; }

template<class... Args>
std::istream& variadic_getline(std::istream& is, Args&&... args)
{
    char delim = is.iword(delimiter());
    if (!delim)
        delim = '\n';

    auto l = { 0, (std::getline(is, std::forward<Args>(args), delim), 0)... };
    (void)l;
    return is;
}
```

Then just do:

```c++
if (variadic_getline(std::cin, p.name, p.dob, p.state, p.best_friend)) {

}
```

Comment: +1 Whoah!!! That might go a bit beyond the OP's actual concepts, but describes this idiom quite well!! Would you mind to add this at my canonical attempt i mentioned in my comment on the question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure thing!

Comment: I'm kinda lost with the `auto l = { 0, (std::getline(is, std::forward<Args>(args), delim), 0)... };` thing ...

Comment: @Chnossos The initializer list is for unpacking the arguments and the first and second zeros are a fail safe in case `Args...` is empty, it won't raise a compile time error. I actually think the zeros aren't needed, as I believe there *should* be an error if `Args..` is empty. But I'd like to make the opposite be the default, and have other users change it to their liking.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'd really appreciate this, to get it available for broader reference! That's one of those frequently asked questions where I'm always trying hard to find an appropriate duplicate (and also mine rarely really applies). Also my initial question attempt might not be _'broad'_ enough, feel free to edit!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to keep all of your strings as an array of strings.

```
struct Person
{
    string data[4];
};
```

Then your operator could be done like this:

```
for ( size_type t = 0 ; t < sizeof(data)/sizeof(string) ; ++t )
{
    getline(cin, p.data[t]);
}
```

You could still have methods for returning the individual fields to keep your code readable.  For example:

```
string& getName() { return data[1]; };
```

I would also define an enum that holds the indexes of the fields to avoid "magic numbers".

Comment: Add a static const array of indexes instead?

Comment: A static const array of indexes won't make it more readable.  I was thinking it would be like this:  `enum Fields { Name, DOB, State };` Then you could do this:  `string& getName() { return data[Name]; };`

Answer (score 0):

If there was some automated way to do this, you would sacrifice having control over the behavior. And there are a million scenarios that would make such a construct useless / impossible (for example, what if you just insert an `int` field in there somewhere?)

With the struct that you have, **no**, there is no way to automatically `getline` into each of the fields. You are forced to put each field name in the type definition, and the location where you assign them.

But you have other methods. For example write your `Person` struct like this:

```
struct Person
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> fields;
};
```

Where `fields` maps a field name (like `"Name"`) to the user-entered string. While you have now enabled fields to be treated as an array, you lose the metadata in your type for the fields. For example with your original code, misspelling `Name` would generate a compiler error. With the `std::map`, `"Naame"` will not generate a compiler error.

And it's for this reason I like your original code best. You pay some copy & paste for type safety and to keep errors at the compiler level.

There are any number of other ways to do this using data structures similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

Basically, make an array of pointers to the various strings, ending with NULL, and iterate through the array, getting each one.

```
void getInput(Person& p)
{
    string* input[]={&p.name, &p.dob, &p.state, NULL};

    for(*input != NULL)
    {
        getline(cin, *input);
        input++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use offsets, than your array can be static const.

Comment: you'd need string** current = input, then use 'current' in the loop. Or use an int to index into input[]. but that seems reasonable

Answer (score 0):

You can use function for this you code it once and then you can use it. You should use reference to the object to write something to it using function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just automating the tedious process is a solution.

If you really want to stay with the multiple `getline()` statements, and you have "many" strings, another solution which is not as "C++ centric" as the other ones mentioned is to write a code generator that generates the `getline` statements from the struct.

The code generator would simply create a file that has all of the `getline` statements, and you just copy/paste these lines in your code (or you can `#include` it as a header file).