# Read input from a .csv file of a linked list

Tags: c++

Im new with the knowledge of reading input from a file so i have no idea where i was wrong 
This is pretty much the code :

```
Reservation* res = new Reservation();    
ifstream fin("data.csv");
                while(!fin.eof()) {
                    fin >> res->ID;
                    fin.get();
                    fin.getline >> res->name;
                    fin.getline >> res->phone;
                    fin >> res->gridironID;
                    fin.get();
                    fin.getline >> res->hireDate;
                    fin.getline >> res->resDate;
                    fin.getline >> res->startTime;
                    fin.getline >> res->endTime;
                    fin >> res->isPay;
                    fin.get();
                    res->nextReservation = reservationHeader;
                    reservationHeader = res;
                }
                fin.close();
            }
```

mine struct :

```
    struct Reservation
    {
int ID;
char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
char phone[MAX_PHONE_LENGTH];
int gridironID;
char hireDate[MAX_DATE_LENGTH];
char resDate[MAX_DATE_LENGTH];
char startTime[MAX_TIME_LENGTH];
char endTime[MAX_TIME_LENGTH];
bool isPay;
Reservation *nextReservation;
    };
```

this is a example of the data.csv file :

```
100001,khang,01283478233,1,1,1,1,1,1
100002,Christina,01283478233,1,1,1,1,1,1
100003,GuanYung,01283478233,1,1,1,1,1,1
100004,kevin,01283478233,1,1,1,1,1,1
100005,minh,01283478233,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

And the errors i keep getting are :

```
Error   10  error C2297: '>>' : illegal, right operand has type 'char [12]' 
Error   13  error C2297: '>>' : illegal, right operand has type 'char [12]' 
Error   5   error C2297: '>>' : illegal, right operand has type 'char [15]' 
//....(this pretty much the same for the other lines)
Error   1   error C3867: 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::getline': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::getline' to create a pointer to member
//...
```

Please help me in any ways possible :(

Comment: As your compiler is trying to say: you're programming in C++, get rid of C stuff. ;) Replace `char name[size];` with `string name;`. When you'll fix that...you'll see you can't use `getline()` because your fields aren't one per line...

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of arrays of `char`s to represent your strings.

Comment: You probably meant `fin.getline(res->name);` and `std::string name;`. Also relevant: [**Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two immediate problems with what you're trying to do:
1. `std::istream >>` doesn't know how to push data into a C-style array.
2. `std::istream` doesn't know that `,` is a valid delimiter.

You're basically out of luck with (1). You can either switch to using C++ `std::string`s instead of C-style strings, or use something other than `>>` to read in data. There are good reasons for keeping C-style strings in your struct, of course, but it is worth considering the alternatives.

Lets stick with C-style strings for the moment. This is a useful function to use:

```
fin.getline(res->name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, ',');
```

This will extract at most `MAX_NAME_LENGTH - 1` characters from the stream (or it will extract character until it finds a comma, whichever comes first). Those characters will be pushed into your character array, which will then be null-terminated (hence why it doesn't extract `MAX_NAME_LENGTH` characters). If it finds a comma, it'll be removed from the stream but not added to your string.

Now, I note that the only condition you check for in your code is `eof()`. This is good, but not enough. You should also check for `fin.fail()`. This will be set if formatted functions failed to extract the type they were asked to, or if `getline` reached the end of its buffer size without seeing a delimiter. Once `failbit` has been set, no other reads will succeed. You should handle this error condition, probably by raising an error, and maybe by clearing it and trying to read the next record as normal and hope that only one record was corrupt.

Now what about delimiters?

By default, `std::istream` expects fields to be space-delimited. This is why if you have comma-separated values, most people end up using `getline` to extract each field.

Turns out that the way stream process text is quite flexible. I've taken this example from the docs here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char

```
// This ctype facet classifies commas and endlines as whitespace
struct csv_whitespace : std::ctype<char> {
  static const mask* make_table()
  {
    // make a copy of the "C" locale table
    static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
    v[','] |= space;  // comma will be classified as whitespace
    v[' '] &= ~space;      // space will not be classified as whitespace
    return &v[0];
  }
  csv_whitespace(std::size_t refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(), false, refs) {}
};

// some function elsewhere in your code
stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), new csv_whitespace()));
```

By modifying the locale of this stream, we have told it that `' '` is no longer a field separator, but `','` is instead. No other streams will be affected.

Now in order to take full advantage of this, you'll have to change from using C-style strings to C++ style `std::string` But once you've done that, everything starts looking much simpler:

```
struct Reservation
{
    int ID;
    std::string name;
    std::string phone;
    int gridironID;
    std::string hireDate;
    std::string resDate;
    std::string startTime;
    std::string endTime;
    bool isPay;
    Reservation *nextReservation;
};

// reading from your imbued stream elsewhere:
while(!fin.eof()) {
  fin >> res->ID >> res->name >> res->phone >> res->gridironID >>
    res->hireDate >> res->resDate >> res->startTime >> res->endTime >>
    res->isPay;

    res->nextReservation = reservationHeader;
    reservationHeader = res;
}
fin.close();
```

Easy, isn't it? Newline characters are still considered field delimiters, so everything should "just work".

Note: neither your code, nor my code, supports "real" csv, with things like quoted strings. If you need that sort of functionality, consider finding a class or library that can do it for you. Doing csv "properly" is trickier than you might think!

Comment: thank you for the instruction kind sir , but the char type is definite as its part of my homework , so i think that the solution here is trying to convert these char into a string by someway possible without changing its type in mine struct .

Comment: so i found a simple method like this : string name = string(res->name);   . Do you think it would work ? Do i need to convert it back to char after i have done fin stuffs?

Comment: You can use something like `std::strncpy(res->name, namestring.c_str(), MAX_NAME_LENGTH);` to move data out of a `std::string` into a `char[]`, but make sure you read the [strncpy docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) carefully, first.