# Reading text file c++ (not able to display other lines)

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream, ifstream, lines

```
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int grade[10];
    double avg=0.00;

    fstream infile("C:\\Users\\Hady Zn\\Desktop\\hady.txt", ios::in);
    fstream outfile("C:\\Users\\Hady Zn\\Desktop\\hady1.txt", ios::out);


    while(infile>>fname>>lname)
    {
        outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" ";
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            grade[i]=0; 

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        infile>>grade[i];

        if(grade[i]>=0 && grade[i]<=100)
        {
        outfile<<grade[i]<<" ";
        avg+=grade[i];
        }

    }

    outfile<<avg/10.00<<endl;
    avg=0.00;

    }
```

So the question is that i need to read from a text file a last name(space) first name(space) then 10 quiz grades(space between each grade) and write the same data into an output file with the average of 10 quizzes at each end of a line. **The problem that im facing is that if i had less than 10 quizzes on one line it will not display the remaining lines.(I want it to still give me the average of the grades given considering for example if i was given 7 grades 3 will be zeros)** I tried solving it but it just won't work. Any ideas that can solve this? Please help. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform such checks, it's better to read the text from the input file line by line and process each line to extract the data.

```
string line
while ( getline(infile, line) )
{
   istringstream sstream(line); 
   sstream >> fname >> lname;
   if (!sstream )
   {
      continue;
   }

   outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" ";
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      grade[i]=0; 
      sstream>>grade[i];
      if ( !sstream )
      {
         break;
      }

      if(grade[i]>=0 && grade[i]<=100)
      {
         outfile<<grade[i]<<" ";
         avg+=grade[i];
      }
   }
}
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP:**

You can avoid reading the input file line by line and processing each line. Here's my suggested changes to the loop.

```
while(infile>>fname>>lname)
{
   outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" ";

   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      grade[i]=0; 
      infile>>grade[i];
      if ( !infile )
      {
         infile.clear();
         break;
      }

      if(grade[i]>=0 && grade[i]<=100)
      {
         outfile<<grade[i]<<" ";
         avg+=grade[i];
      }
   }

   outfile<<avg/10.00<<endl;
   avg=0.00;

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `infile >> line` be `getline(infile, line)`.

Comment: Better `while ( getline(infile,line) )`

Comment: I agree with you on the reading line by line idea. But may i ask if there's any way around strings? or that's the only possible way?

Comment: @0x499602D2 and πάντα ῥεῖ, thanks for pointing out the oversight. It's fixed now.

Comment: @RSahu wow thanks a lot! The second method works great, but i couldn't tell the mistake i was making in my program. can you shed some light on it please?

Comment: @HadyZn, The key difference is the call `infile.clear()` and breaking out of the `for` loop when there is an error in reading a grade. Check out [the documentation for `istream::clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/)

Comment: @RSahu Would you like to contribute an answer to the Q&A I have marked as dupe? I would appreciate that.