# Parsing string containing delimiters

Tags: c++, string

I have a string value 'func1/50/70'

I need to parse it so that I have 'func1' as a string and both 50 and 70 as int values.

Can any C++, arduino experts help?

Comment: Can't see anything [tag:arduino] specific in your question.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think it is off-topic, just duplicated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe I'm reading the edited question and it was worse before? I think it's fine as it is now, it is not too broad, as demonstrated by the fact that at least two duplicated questions exist.

Comment: @MisterSmith It's not fine, it's "gimme teh codez" question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Arduino C allows. In C++ you can try std::find, that can return a pointer to something to be found. In this case you'd try to find the "/"