# Reading from .csv

Tags: c++, file, csv

So I am reading from the .csv as showed as the result is shown in the image url. When I'm cout-ing everything what's in the file it prints additional " " between the every read cell. So I'm wondering why are these " " cout-ed? **And most importantly is there a way to get rid of them?**

[image]

```
void Evidenca::IskanjeIstiVnos(vector<Evidenca>& evidenc, vector<Evidenca>& kopir, fstream &Datoteka){
string vrstica;
int StVrstic=0;
int Stej;
string TEMPsemester;
string TEMPletnik;
string TEMPects;
string TEMPocIzpita;



while(!Datoteka.eof()){ 
    getline(Datoteka,vrstica,'\n');
    Datoteka >> ws;
    StVrstic++;
}

Datoteka.clear();
Datoteka.seekg(0, ios::beg);

cout << "Stevilo predmetov zapisanih v datoteki je: " << StVrstic<<endl; //How many lines are in file

for(int a=0;a<StVrstic;a++){
getline(Datoteka,ImePredmeta,';');
getline(Datoteka,ProfesorImPr,';');
getline(Datoteka,TEMPsemester,';');
getline(Datoteka,TEMPletnik,';');
getline(Datoteka,TEMPects,';');
getline(Datoteka,datumIzpita,';');
getline(Datoteka,TEMPocIzpita,'\n');
cout << ImePredmeta << " " << ProfesorImPr << " "<< TEMPsemester << " " << TEMPletnik << " " << TEMPects << " " << datumIzpita << " " << TEMPocIzpita << endl;


}
```

Comment: Because they are in the .csv file?

Comment: Those quotes are in your file, open it with a text editor.

Comment: `while(!Datoteka.eof()){ ` Stop it!

Comment: Here are some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: Why down vote? this question seems valid.

Answer (score 2):

`getline` doesn't make up characters. Those characters are read from your CSV file : you can see them if you open it with a text editor (emacs, vi, notepad..), they are automatically hidden in Excel-like software.

Comment: Thank you, Ignored all those " " so I fixed it.