# how to test for white space c++:

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to parse a .csv file, and I need to be able to test for a carriage return. Here is a test .csv file called sample.csv:

```
2
3
```

As you'll notice, there are two rows and one column in this file. I now write the following C++ code:

```
ifstream myfile (sample.csv); //Import file
char nextchar;

myfile.get(nextchar);
cout<<nextchar<<'\n';

myfile.get(nextchar);
cout<< nextchar<<"   If 0, then that was not a carriage return. If 1, it was. :"<<(nextchar=='\n')<<'\n';

myfile.get(nextchar);
cout<<nextchar<<'\n';
```

I expect the following output:

```
2
   If 0, then that was not a carriage return. If 1, it was. :1
3
```

however, I get:

```
2
   If 0, then that was not a carriage return. If 1, it was. :0
3
```

How is this possible? how do I test for a carriage return??

Comment: Have you tried `getline()`?

Comment: on Win platform there is a possibility of '\r' since they use \r\n for newline.

Comment: Any particular reason you are implementing it this way? Why not use `std::getline()`?

Comment: because then the function takes much less lines of code - I have one while loop, and it handles the 3 cases of ',', '\n', and 'int', using an if/else if structure

Comment: @Andro47 I have a mac - I'm using terminal on OSX

Comment: @user3713167 You may get some ideas how to do this from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: hahahaha it's you again - I fear the inquisition - I'm new to programming - I haven't taken any computer science classes yet - spare me!

Comment: @user3713167 Looks you followed mattnewport's advice, and not mine. I told you, you're barfing up the wrong tree ;) ...

Comment: @user3713167 In particular you may check the idea given of a `delim_field_extractor_proxy` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23070803/1413395) (check the note and the [linked sample there](http://ideone.com/ZwEARz)). That's all you need for parsing `.csv` formats with a specified delimiter character. Also your `.csv` sample is degenerate and a simple `std::getline()` and trying to parse the values from a `std::istringstream` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a pair of characters CR + LF. In any case you could output the code of this character yourself. Why did not you do this?
Also you could apply standard function `std::isspace` decalred in header `<cctype>`

I suggest to use standard function `std::getline` to read a whole line instead of using get.

Comment: so (nextchar=='\n') should be instead (nextchar=='\r\n')?

Comment: @user3713167 I wrote clear that instead of one character '\n' there may be two characters: '\r' and '\n'

Comment: @user3713167 well 'hard coding' any combination is very non-portable (in sense of parsing files ofc). Hence the beauty of getline()

Comment: @Andro47 Of course that's not portable, that's why Vlad proposed to use `std::getline()`, which is!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, that was the answer to OP's sub question on `so (nextchar=='\n') should be instead (nextchar=='\r\n')?`

Comment: I used std::isspace - great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that can go wrong in the assumptions:  OS behaviour, the text editor used to write the sample file, an undesired extra space or tab at the end of line, and the `ios_base::openmode` used to open the file, as well as all possible combination between those...

First instert this line to see what you actually read:  is it 0x0d or 0x0a ?  or somthing else ?

```
cout << "Char read: 0x0"<< std::hex << (int)nextchar<<"\n"; 
cout << "If 0 ...          // Existing line
```

You can also replace your sample with the following. It opens the file in **binary mode** and display in hex the chars really in the file :

```
ifstream myfile ("sample.csv", ifstream::binary); //Import file
while (myfile.good() )  {
    char nextchar;
    myfile.get(nextchar);
    if (myfile.good())
        cout << "0x0"<< std::hex << (int)nextchar
                         << " " << (isprint(nextchar)? nextchar:'?') <<"\n";
}
```

If second and third line are 0x0d and 0x0a, you'll know for sure that your text editor has put the extra CR.

Then you can remove `ifstream::binary` in the code above.  Normally you should have, as you pointed out only 0x0a in the second line. If it's not the case, then you should investigate if the default openmode was somehow altered.

By the way, I've compiled your original code under windows and prepared the sample file using notepad , ran the programm and got... what you did expect !  Then I've redone the test with the following modification and the finally got what you got.

Good luck  !