# Modify input stream data on the fly

Tags: c++, iostream

I would like to implement a *std::stream* modifier/parser, that is doing data manipulation on the fly.

Is it possible to create it in form of stream manipulator? For example, i want to strip all the line comments (from any `//` to the end of line) out of the stdin and pass it to stdout.

```
string str;
istream strippingCin = cin >> stripcomments;

while(strippingCin.good())
{
    strippingCin >> str;
    cout << str;
}
```

There may be also a large file input instead of cin, so i don't want to load full stream data into memory at once.

Is it possible without writing my own stream class?

Maybe is there another route i should take instead?

Comment: That's a no way better question than _'Gimme teh codez plz!'_ and wanting _'Can I has cheezeburgers as well?'_!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sounds like fantasy novel.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Asking for good example of how to do that, because I have no clue. Not found such stuff anywhere else.

Comment: You may research about implementing appropriate [I/O stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), or s.th. like this. Also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) might have some useful pointers for solutions you can use.

Comment: iomanipulators alter the state of the stream, but this isn't something streams are capable of doing by default.  I think a custom streambuf could do it, but that's definitely a violation of separation of concerns.  I think it'd be wiser to make an iterator, or maybe even a lexer.

Comment: @Frizi _'Is it possible without writing my own stream class?'_ In terms of generally ignoring `//` to EOL comments from the input, I'm afraid the answer is No. (concentrate your research for implementing a [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) interface, rather than looking out how to implement the full `std::istream` interface!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`boost::iostreams::filtering_stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/?path=4.2.5.7) is perfect for this.  After you write a filtering class (see the similar example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/?path=2.2.3.2)), you would just do:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream strippingCin;
strippingCin.push(StripCommentsFilter());
strippingCin.push(std::cin);
```

and the `istream` object `strippingCin` is ready to use.