# C++ Code Dumping "random" data

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, codeblocks, dump

I will start by saying I am reasonably new as a C++ programmer.
However I understand PHP and VBA, so have a good understanding of the aspects of programming fundamentals.

Because I use CSV's quite often in my day to day job, I thought it would be a good learning exercise to write a library that manipulates CSV Files.

I wrote this function:

```
int getHeaders(ifstream & os, vector<string> & head2){
    string STRING;
    getline(os,STRING);
    cout << STRING << endl;
    STRING.erase(remove(STRING.begin(), STRING.end(), '\"'), STRING.end());
    string::iterator it = STRING.begin();
    int x = 0;
    for (int index = 0; it < STRING.end(); it++, index++) {
        if (*it == ',') {
            head2.push_back(STRING.substr(0,index));
            STRING.erase(0,index+1);
            cout << endl << head2[x];
            cout << endl << STRING;
            x++;
        }
    }
    return head2.size();
}
```

Which is called by the following:

```
int addRowCount = 0;
vector<string> head1;

ifstream outfile;
outfile.open("default.csv", ios_base::app);

cout << getHeaders(outfile, head1) << endl;
cout << head1[0] << endl << head1[1] << endl;
```

But when I run the program, the program just dumps a load of random rubbish to the console (and crashes the application)
I am using windows so cannot use valgrind.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? Obviously this "dump" is not what I want the application to do. I am hoping someone can point out the part of my code which would make this happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: How do you feel this is related?
I have used no structs. Please bear in mind I am new to C++ and just looking for some pointers?

Comment: @rhysowen What does your program do when `default.csv` can't be found in the correct directory?

Comment: @Drew Dormann At the moment, nothing as I am currently at "concept" stage. But "default.csv" does exist (infact, another part of this program created and wrote to it)

Comment: @rhysowen _'How do you feel this is related?'_  Check this answer about abstraction for the reading of character delimited text-formats: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23070803/1413395

Comment: It is worth me noting that the function was working fine until I turned it from a `void` to an `int` that also modified a `vector`

Comment: @rhysowen You could simply have used `string::find_first_of` instead of looping until you find a `','` character.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, will definitely look to utilise that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that head2[1] wasn't set so it was some sort of memory leak.

Here is the finished function after a few further amendments for the advice in the comments section:

```
int getHeaders(ifstream & os, vector<string> & head2){
    string STRING;
    getline(os,STRING);
    STRING.erase(remove(STRING.begin(), STRING.end(), '\"'), STRING.end());
    int strle = count(STRING.begin(),STRING.end(), ',') + 1;
    for(int x = 0; x != strle; x++){
        if (count(STRING.begin(), STRING.end(), ',') > 0) {
            head2.push_back(STRING.substr(0,STRING.find_first_of(',')));
        } else {
            head2.push_back(STRING.substr(0,STRING.length()));
        }
        STRING.erase(0,STRING.find_first_of(',')+1);
    }
    return head2.size(); 
}
```

Comment: If people are going to downvote this answer could you at least tell me why?

Comment: If you are interested in improving your C++ skills, I would suggest posting your *working* code on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, if you haven't already, I would take a look at the first snippet of code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1120224/3033711). It is a much cleaner way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jliv902 I wasn't aware of the Code Review Stack Exchange! Will definitely start using that. And also that link to that other question will prove very useful when I start to review the complexity of my functions. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When you call erase on a string, iterators into that string are invalidated, so it is an error to use `it` after the call to `STRING.erase()`.

*Hint*: When you look at the documentation for a method on a class that supports iterators, keep an eye out for notes about invalidating iterators.   On [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/), for example, read the section titled `Iterator validity`

[not related to the answer, but a style issue:  Using ALL CAPS for a variable name like STRING  is generally considered bad style in C and C++.  All caps names are used for #defined symbols]