# C++ File input with various variables

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to create a load function for a program. So wrote this to save my information. I dont really have a preference whether to keep everything for each competitor on the same row but this looked simplest.

```
void GameHandler::WriteToFile()
{
    ofstream file ("Competitors.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file<<this->mNrOfCompetitors<<"\n";
        for(int i=0; i<this->mNrOfCompetitors; i++)
        {
            file<<this->mCompetitors[i].GetName()<<"\n";
            file<<this->mCompetitors[i].GetDateOfBirth()<<"\n";
            file<<this->mCompetitors[i].GetGender()<<"\n";
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Unable to write to file."<<endl;
    }
}
```

But now when I have to load everything in. People have the wierdest tutorials that basically handles the simplest of cases. Which is why i need some help.

I started off but this doesnt work because i dont know how do a lineswitch in the input.

```
void GameHandler::LoadFromFile()
{
    cleanup(); //Erase current data and replace with loaded data.

    string linestring;
    int lineint;
    bool linebool;


    ifstream file ("Competitors.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file>>this->mNrOfCompetitors;

        this->mCapacity = this->mNrOfCompetitors+5;
        this->mCompetitors = new Duathlet[this->mCapacity];


        for(int i=0; i<this->mNrOfCompetitors; i++)
        {
            file>>linestring;
            this->mCompetitors[i].SetName(linestring);
            //need lineswitch
            file>>lineint;
            this->mCompetitors[i].SetDateOfBirth(lineint);
            //need lineswitch
            file>>linebool;
            this->mCompetitors[i].SetGender(linebool);
            //need lineswitch
        }


        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open file."<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are some pointers how to do it: [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: You need std::getline for reading a complete line, which may contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What do u think about [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)? If u have problem with endlines u can also [get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) this endline char('\n') like, for example 
`char x; file.get(x)` -> now '\n' will be taken.
Other solution is [ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) for example `file.ignore(666, '\n')`