# How do separate a string from a text file

Tags: c++, string

I have a text file that has information format like this:

> id last,first string

for example:

> 0 Snow,John nothing
>
> 1 Norris,Chuck everything

How do i get last name and first name stored separately?

To get information from file, I did:

```
#include <fstream>

int id;
string str;
string last;
string first;

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile(ex.txt);

    myfile >> id;

    while (myfile)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // this is the amount of times i'll get information from 1 line

        {
            id = id; // its actually some_structure.id = id, omit

            getline(myfile, last, ','); // i think i need to use another function as getline get the whole line

            cout << id;

            cout << last; // print out the whole line!

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Some pointers, what can be actually done, to read from structured (field delimited) text input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: If you try to store Chuck Norris, he'll punch his way out.... ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ifstream myfile;
string line;
while (getline(myfile, line))
{
    istringstream ss(line);
    int id;
    ss >> id;
    string fullname;
    ss >> fullname;
    string firstname, lastname;
    {
        istringstream ss2(fullname);
        getline(ss2, lastname, ',');
        getline(ss2, firstname);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Would be even better with some (beginner) comprehensible explanations!

Comment: `getline()` function reads a line from file into a string `line`.
`istringstream` class will convert `line` into an input stream `ss`
then every time you use `>>` operator the input stream will use space as default delimiter and chunk the input line into smaller parts that you need, i.e. `id` and `fullname`.
then do it again to chunk down `fullname` into `firstname` and `lastname` using `,` as delimiter

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added an edit but it did not register... maybe too low rep?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (std::ifstream input(filename))
{
    int id;
    string lastname, firstname, other_string;
    while (input >> id && getline(input, lastname, ',') &&
           input >> firstname >> other_string)
        ... do whatever you like...
    if (!input.eof())
        std::cerr << "error while parsing input\n";
}
else
    std::cerr << "error while opening " << filename << '\n';
```

The code above has more error checking than the other answers I've seen, but admittedly - because it doesn't read text a line at a time then parse out the fields, it would happily accept e.g.:

```
10 Chuck,
Norris whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Would recomend something like this:

```
string name;
myfile >> id >> name >> str;
first = name.substr(0, name.find(","));
last = name.substr(name.find(",") + 1);
```

Note that your EOF checking is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

// The complete code that will do the job
// Please remove uncomment all code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("ex.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
            string last  = line.substr(line.find(" ") + 1, line.find(",") - 2);
            string first = line.substr(line.find(",") + 1, line.find(",") + line.find(" ") - 1); 
        }
        myfile.close();
    }    
    else { 
        cout << "Unable to open file"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use properly embraced `{ /* ... */ }` blocks!