# How to parse a line according to special character?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, special-characters

```
absc|238066463|xyxz|A9BCV9.1|RIMO_PROM4
```

I want to split it according to ("|"). It is a simple task to do in python, however in c++
what should I do?

I used `boost::split`, but it does not work?

```
line="absc|238066463|xyxz|A9BCV9.1|RIMO_PROM4"
vector<string> tokens;
boost::split(tokens,line,boost::is_any_of("|"));
cout<<tokens[0]<<"\t"<<tokens[1]<<endl;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What problem are you having with `boost::split`? It works fine for me. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4edb5f69c05ef5f

Comment: i will double check...i got random letters ....after I run it...

Comment: Please present a complete, compileable code example that demonstrates the problem, along with your expected vs. actual results.

Comment: Check this answer: [**Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23070803/1413395). It should definitely help to solve your problem (no [tag:boost] needed).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this. One that avoids external libraries, but is still fairly simple and straightforward looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const &input, char sep) { 
    std::istringstream buffer(input);

    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::string token;

    while (std::getline(buffer, token, sep))
        ret.push_back(token);
    return ret;
}
```

This isn't the fastest method possible, but string tokenization isn't typically critical.