# c++ inputing a string - not with getline() but with cin

Tags: c++, string, iostream

Inputting a string with spaces!

Here is what I was thinking:

```
string name;
std::cout << "Please enter your full name: ";
std::cin >> std::noskipws;
while (std::cin >> name >> std::ws) {
    full_name += name + " ";
}
```

Say your name was Bill Billy Bobby Bronson Billson.

or maybe something like adding:

```
if (name == "\n")
  break;
```

With getline(), it's one statement. However, I don't want to use getline() for research reasons.

Can it be done?

**Update:**

If I try my code I get an infinite loop no matter what I change.

Comment: If you try your code what happens? For the example input, what is the result?

Comment: Here are some pointers what you can do to use alternate input delimiters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd really want to do so, but yes, this is possible.

`operator>>` for `std::string` reads input characters until it encounters a white-space character. A stream has a ctype facet that it uses to determine whether a character is white space or not.

In this case, you want a ctype facet that *only* classifies `\n` as white space.

```
struct line_reader: std::ctype<char> {
    line_reader(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());

        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

You imbue your input file with an instance of a locale that includes that ctype facet:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    // Tell the stream to use our facet, so only '\n' is treated as a space.
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new line_reader()));

    // to keep things at least a little interesting, we'll copy lines from input
    // to output if (and only if) they contain at least one space character:
    std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
        [](std::string const &s) {
            return s.find(' ') != std::string::npos;
    });
}
```

Here I've used `std::istream_iterator`, which uses the extraction operator for the specified type (`std::string` in this case) to read the data.