# How to incorporate a large list of numbers into a c++ code

Tags: c++, arrays, excel

I have four lists each containing 84 different rates which I want to be able to access using if/else statements based on the inputted information and I was hoping there was something more efficient than typing each one into an array.

What would be the easiest way to do this? Any hints would be very helpful I just need a starting point.

```
   #include "MaleNonSmoker.txt"  
    using namespace std;  
    double ratesmn[85] = {  
    #include "MaleNonSmoker.txt"  

        - 1  
   };  
    #include <iostream>  
    #include <string>  
    #define STARTAGE 15  
    int main() {  
        double const *rates;  
        rates = ratesmn;  
        int age;  
            cout << "How old are you?\n";  
cin >> age;  
double myrate = ratesmn[age - STARTAGE];  

        return 0; 
    }
```

The errors that I am getting are from line 1: syntax error: 'constant'
and from line 7: 'too many initializers'

Comment: Why not having the numbers in a separated file?

Comment: or just...anywhere. Who told you an array has to be populated by the user at runtime?

Comment: But then how do I access the numbers in the separate file? For instance, I want to prompt the user to say whether they are a "male" or "female" and a "smoker" or "nonsmoker" and then using these inputs I would make if/else statements to find the correct rate and go from there. How would I take the correct rate from a separate file to use in my equation?

Comment: @TheIntern If you're asking on this level, it's best you work through a basic c++ book, before starting with your project.

Comment: array's being populated by the user at runtime was the only way I learned how to make arrays. I only took an introduction to c++ course at school. I'm not sure how to use or even make a pre-made array

Comment: This is GentlePurpleRain's answer (in case he deletes his): You can define an array of numbers in C++ like this:

`int[6] rates = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

Comment: @  πάντα ῥεῖ I took an entire course on c++. I'm not completely clueless I just need a start

Comment: @TheIntern Do I understand it correctly you want to export the numbers out of excel into your c++ code as easy as possible?

Comment: @Ben Thank you that is very helpful. But wouldn't it be easier to have a separate text file of my 4 tables and then use them accordingly? Is there an easy way to do this? The goal is to be able to use this calculator to find several different people's premiums under many different circumstances. Having to type in the rates each time would not be very efficient

Comment: @Wimmel it does not necessarily have to be out of excel. But I would like to use the numbers from anywhere as easy as possible without having to type them in while the program is running. Also, I need to be able to choose which list of numbers I want to use based on their age, gender, and whether they smoke or not

Comment: @TheIntern _'But then how do I access the numbers in the separate file?'_ [This answer may give you a clue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23070803/1413395), how you could deal with `.csv` style data.

Comment: Are these rates going to vary between runs? 84*4=336 numbers, that's not a lot. What's wrong with `int list1[84] = {...}; int list2[84] = {...}; int list3[84] = {...}; int list4[84] = {...};`. Then use logic to decide which list you're picking numbers from.

Comment: Really all this talk about where to put it is just splitting hairs...

Comment: Use [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers do not change, there is no real need to read the numbers at runtime from a file. You can also use them at compile time.

Create four files with the arrays with any tool you like, but a comma after each number so it looks like this:

```
51,
52,
53,
```

In your c++ code, define 4 arrays, and use `#include` to include the numbers from the text file;

```
int ratesms[85] = {

#include "ratesms.txt"

    -1 // add another number because the txt file ends with a comma
};
```

Do the same for the other arrays.

In your code determine which list you want to use, and set a pointer to that list, for example

```
int const *rates;

if ( /* smoking male */ )
  rates = ratesms;
else if ( /* other variations */ )
  rates = ...
```

And then use it like this;

```
#define STARTAGE 15

int age=35; // example
int myrate=rates[age-STARTAGE];
```

If you don't want to substract the start age from the array index, you can also add 15 dummy  numbers to the array;

```
int ratesms[100] = {

    0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,

#include "ratesms.txt"

    -1 // add another number because the txt file ends with a comma
};
```

now `ratesms[15]` will contain the first number from the txt file.

Comment: Thank you! This is very very helpful. I will try this out and see how far it get's me. Might be back on here soon if I get stuck!

Comment: sure, I saw in another comment you are using floats instead of integers, but that will work too if you change the types in the code.

Comment: one more thing, the lists are from age 15 to 99. So if the person being insured is 35, I want to start at the 20th rate (35 - 15) so that the correct age's rate is being used. Then as the person gets a year older, it moves down and uses the next year's rate. How do I choose the correct year to start?

Comment: I am not sure if that is what you mean, but I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: For example before the `int main()`. If your program gets larger, you will probably start to use multiple c++ files. Then you can use a separate file, and a .h file with a declaration.

Comment: I am getting an error that says : IntelliSense cannot open source file "MaleNonSmoker.txt" which is a file I made of my first list

Comment: make sure your MaleNonSmoker.txt is in the same directory as the .cpp file in which you include it.

Comment: Last comment then I think I should be okay for a little while. You are a big help, thank you. It is saying that it is expecting a declaration in my .txt file

Comment: Check if it is just IntelliSense which complains. That does not very important. More important is whether it compiles. It should be possible to disable IntelliSense, but I don't remember how.

Comment: I keep trying to post my code as a comment to show you but it will not put in line breaks it just has a space. I am brand new to stack exchange how can I show you what I've done so far?

Comment: I added my code to the initial question

Comment: 'too many initializers' means basically too many numbers. Which is good, because that means you did something wrong, so you have to fix that. Putting newlines in comments is not possible. In your case you basically have a new question, you should post that as a new question, so others can reply while I am away. Asking questions is free. Of course you can notify me about the new question in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of numbers in C++ like this:

`int[6] rates = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

Comment: Doesn't really make sense for large amounts of data.

Comment: He mentioned 4 different lists of 84 numbers.  That seems small enough to me to include in the code.

Comment: Check the OP's answer to Ben's comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

What's the format of your "lists?"

Reading them in should be very simple -- check out [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) tutorial on file I/O in C++. If you save your lists as simple .txt files, you can read each list item line by line by creating an ifstream and calling getline(). The file data will be read as strings, so you can use stoi() and stod() to convert them to integers and doubles, respectively (check out [the string reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) for more conversion methods).

You also might want to look into saving your excel files as comma-separated-value (.csv) files, which can then be read in line by line in the same manner. Each line will represent a row with cell values separated by commas, which are very easy to parse.