# Using my sales_data class to write a simple program

Tags: c++

I'm completing the following exercise from a book:

> Using your `sales_data` class write a program that reads several
>   transaction for the same isbn and counts how many times each isbn
>   occurs

I have already written such program in which I had to enter a list of numbers and then print out how many times each number appeared.

This is the definition of my class that the book provides me to accomplish this task:

```
#ifndef SALES_DATA_H
#define SALES_DATA_H 
#include <string>

struct Sales_data {

std::string bookNo;
unsigned units_sold = 0;
double revenue = 0;
};
#endif
```

This is the input that the program should receive:

```
0-201-78345 1-x 19.99 (ISBN, units_sold, price to book)

0-201-78345 1-x 19.99 (same ISBN)

2-201-78345-z 2 26.99
```

The output should be:

```
0-201-78345 x-1 OCCURS 2 times

2-201-78345-z OCCURS 1 times
```

My program, rather than reading all of the ISBNs and printing the counters, only prints the counters as soon as the isbns are different.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_data.h"
#include <string>


int main()
{

Sales_data currVal,val; 
double price = 0; 

if (std::cin >> currVal.bookNo >> currVal.units_sold >> price) {
int cnt = 1; 

while (std::cin >> val.bookNo >> val.units_sold >> price) {

if (currVal.bookNo == val.bookNo)
++cnt; 

else {
std::cout << currVal.bookNo << " occurs" << cnt << " times" << std::endl; 
currVal = val; 
cnt = 1;

}//end of else
}//end of while

std::cout << currVal.bookNo << " occurs" << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
}// end of outhermost if 

system("pause");
}
```

Also, my program does not print the last ISBN if you do not insert the sequence of end-of-file.

Comment: You know that `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::string str)` reads `str` delimited by white space (i.e. word by word)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: You need to move the content of the `else` clause outside, after the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `std::map`:

```
typedef std::map<Sales_Data, unsigned int> Container_Type;
Container_Time inventory;
//...
Sales_Data item;

// Assume Sales_Data has overloaded operator>>.
while (std::cin >> item)
{
  Container_Type::iterator iter = inventory.find(item);
  if (iter != inventory.end())
  {
    iter->second++; // Increment the occurances.
  }
  else
  {
     // New item, add to container.
     inventory[item] = 1;
  }
}
```

The above code also assumes that `Sales_Data` overloads `operator==` and `operator<`.

After reading, iterate through the container, printing the item and its number of occurrences.