# C++ reading txt file and cout values not reading whole file

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to read in some values in a `txt file` like so

```
val1 val2 val3
val1 val2 val3
val1 val2 val3
```

Then I am trying to `cout` to the terminal when I compile the program. 
The problem I am having is the first line of the text file gets read and prints fine but then I get to random `0 0` values and then nothing else....

I have no clue where to go from here even to troubleshoot cause I don't get any errors.

I will add that the program doesn't `cout` anything when compiling in `Xcode` but when ran from the terminal it shows the line as I explained.

I was thinking maybe this is cause the way my `for loop` for the `vector` while `cout`?

```
struct Input{
    std::string group;
    float total_pay;
    unsigned int quantity;

    Input(std::string const& groupIn, float const& total_payIn, unsigned int const& quantityIn):
    group(groupIn),
    total_pay(total_payIn),
    quantity(quantityIn)
    {}
};

int main(){

    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    std::vector<Input> data;

    std::string group;
    std::string total_pay;
    std::string quantity;

    std::getline(infile,group);
    std::getline(infile,total_pay);
    std::getline(infile,quantity);

    while (infile){
        data.push_back(Input(group,atof(total_pay.c_str()),atoi(quantity.c_str())));

        std::getline(infile,group);
        std::getline(infile,total_pay);
        std::getline(infile,quantity);
    }


    //output
    for(Input values : data){
        std::cout << values.group << " " << values.total_pay << " " << values.quantity << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think `getline` gets a single word? its get**line**, you need to get the whole line then tokenise it (or use `stringstream`)

Comment: Show the real stuff as a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here pleaae! Also related: [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: Well yea I guess I am confused. So if my values are per line in my txt file is`group total_pay quantity` where is my error?

Comment: I think your code is correct, because it ran as you expected when the code ran from terminal.

Comment: When text file contains three lines of "val1 val2 val3", "val4 val5 val6","val7 val8 val9", what output do you expect on cout?

Comment: ya but its not going to the next line.

Comment: I expect it to read every line in the txt file and output every value that is stored inside the struct.