# Read at once inputs string and integer separated by a space in c++

Tags: c++, input

I was wondering if, like in C, in C++ there was a way to take at once two different type of varibales as inputs.
For example I am supposed to read a command (a string) followed by an index(an integer) from a user, and they separated by a space.

Comment: `string a;int b;cin>>a>>b;`

Comment: I had some answers collected [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi).

Comment: This is soooo close to being a duplicate of many *read from file* questions that I couldn't begin to mark it as duplicate. Please search for keywords before you post (it's often faster).

Comment: what do you mean by "at once"?

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator for a `std::istream` is [overloaded for many different types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). Any class which inherits `>>` from `std::istream` can read inputs from all the types `>>` is overloaded for. This means you can use the `>>` operator with `std::cin`, `std::ifstream`, `std::istringstream`, etc. to read in multiple types.

The basic syntax for your case would have the form

```
std::string s;
int n;

std::cin >> s >> n; // or std::ifstream, etc.
```

Of course you should perform error checking to make sure you actually received what you expected. You can use the `!` operator to check if the stream is (not) in a good state. So in your case you might use the following:

```
std::string s;
int n;

if (!std::cin) {
  // error handling here
} else {
  std::cin >> s; // get the std::string
}

if (!std::cin) {
  // error handling here
} else {
  std::cin >> n; // get the int
}
```