# c++ is next line of text file char or int?

Tags: c++, text-files

I am writing a program for a video rental store that originally reads in the video information, customer information, and some customer's rented movies from a text file. The data file format gives the number of videos but not the number of customers. After reading in the video information, I need a way to determine how many customers exist by parsing the file. The file format is something like this:

number of videos
video title
actor
producer
director
video title
actor
.
.
.
customer first name, customer last name, customer ID number
.
.
customer ID number, rental, rental
.
.

The only way I can think to make this work with out reading in the number of customers from the file would be to determine if the next line starts with a char or an int. Is there any way to determine this? Not all customers have a rental record in the file.

Comment: Why not use any kind of SQL (SQLite, MySQL, ...) for storing your data?

Comment: .csv / .ssv should do the trick.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) you can find some hints for how to approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file line by line instead of field by field.  Having a whole line in memory (as a string) you can evaluate what type of line it is, and parse it appropriately.

Comment: I have been reading in line by line into string variables and creating video and customer objects in for loops. How would I be able to test the contents of the string to see if the first element is a customer number or customer name if it is stored in a string? I need to know when to stop creating customer objects and start adding rentals to existing customers.

Comment: That depends a bit on your data, but supposing that customer IDs are numeric, that customer names never start with a digit, and that lines have no leading whitespace, you can judge by the first character of the line.  If it's a digit then you have a rental record; otherwise you have a customer record.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. However, I do not know how to test the first character of a string to see if it is a digit or character. Any ideas?

Comment: Whether you are using a C-style string or a `std::string`, you can access the first `char` of a nonempty string `s` as `s[0]`.  The safest way to determine whether a char corresponds to a decimal digit is the `isdigit()` function, but you'll often see people instead evaluate `('0' <= s[0]) && (s[0] <= '9')`.  The latter works in most environments, probably including yours, but it is not *guaranteed* to work.