# c++ edit txt file by element

Tags: c++, file

I have a txt file where I keep the information which is arranged in this order:

```
Name somename
Age someAge
Address someAddress
...
```

I look for this information by elements like this:

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile >> element1)
    {
        myfile >> element2;

        if (element1 == "Name")
            _name = element2; //element2 is someName in .txt file

        if (element1 == "Age")
            _age = element2; //element2 is someAge in .txt file
        ...
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

and so on ...

It is possible to edit the txt file this way too using ofstream?

Comment: Do you want to edit an existing text file or write data to a new text file? Have you considered using a database?

Comment: Edit an existing file, forgive me for not mentioning. 
I will probably have to use, I've thought about it, but I can see if I can get around without database, since the information is not very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"It is possible to edit the txt file this way too using `ofstream`?"*

Yes, it's possible. Just not in an immediate way manipulating the file contents (as you might be considering of).

1. You read in the file using a `std::ifstream` line by line into a `std::vector<std::string>` variable
2. You manipulate these lines using the various `std::string` functions as needed
3. You open the same file as `std::ofstream` (use `std::iosbase::trunc` flag for opening)
4. You write all of your `std::vector<std::string>` variables to the output file

---

As [@Jerry Coffin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218129/c-edit-txt-file-by-element/29218245#comment46645704_29218245), you may consider creating a backup of the manipulated file in 1st place. If you do so, you also could take advantage from manipulating *single records*, without needing to read in the complete file (could lead to memory issues, if it's really big).

Comment: @NunoBarão You might also consider to use kinda `struct Person;` to structure the information read in a more concise manner. Here are some pointers, how to do that properly: [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi).

Comment: Just note that (at least as stated) this has a "danger zone". If (for example) the machine loses power after truncating the stream, but before writing the new contents, you could get an empty or corrupted file. If that's a serious problem, you could copy the file to a backup, then truncate and write, and when that completes delete the backup. If a backup file exists when the program starts, there was a problem and it can react accordingly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah, I was thinking about moving the file to a backup, and creating the new one just reading in one line, manipulate that one and output to the file again, but this could be problematic as well (depends on how editing should be done with the file). It sounded more like the OP's searching for kinda _database record_ editing approach.