# How to read from a file and store variables?

Tags: c++, file, for-loop, while-loop, getline

I'm making a program to calculate student's quiz averages and class average, while using a loop to simplify it and storing the data to a file (just a .txt for now).

I'm new to c++ and this is probably the most advanced thing I've worked on so far...

My current code is:

```
// Grade Average calculator

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream outputFile;
    ifstream inputFile;
    int continueYes;
    double  qz, score;
    string studentId;

    //Open File
    outputFile.open("quizav.txt");
    //Continue to start...
    cout << "Press 1 to add a student, Press 0 to exit.\n";
    cin >> continueYes;

    while (continueYes == 1){
        cout << "Please Enter student ID: ";
        cin >> studentId;

        outputFile << studentId << " ";

        for (qz = 1; qz < 5; qz++){
            cout << "Enter quiz score " << qz << " ";
            cin >> score;

            +-score;
            outputFile << " " << score << " ";
        }

        cout << "Press 1 to add a student, press 0 if no more.\n";
        cin >> continueYes;
        outputFile << " " << endl;

    }

    outputFile.close();

    //OUT PUT FINISHED
    double average;
    double student, studentInfo;
    inputFile.open("quizav.txt");

    while (inputFile >> studentInfo){

        cout << studentInfo << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

While  the top half works fine, and stores the information in a text file like so

```
student id  score, score, score
student id  score, score, score
etc.
```

I am not sure what to make my while and for loop on the bottom to give output roughly to my desired:

student 1's average: average
student 2's average: average
etc

class average:

The current While/for loop at the bottom display the right information from the file, just not in the right matter (no gaps between student IDs)

I really need it to get one line at a time, average it, and store the total to average it later.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you already step through the reading part with a debugger line by line? May be you rather want to use `std::getline()` to read a whole record 1st, and split for the interesting values in it (e.g. using `std::istringstream`).

Comment: I attempted to use a getline, but it would not work with how I had it, could you use an example of one of these? It doesn't need to be extremely specific.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the plethora of similar question?  Try this search:  [stackoverflow c++ read file parameters](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+read+from+file+parameters&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Of course, I've got some Q&A at hand, that might give you a grip what's necessary to do with the line. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) please. Both samples use `std::getline()` and `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code to your existing code, after the comment "Output Finished"

```
double studentInfo;
inputFile.open("quizav.txt");

int count = 0, numstudents = 0, numquizzes = 4;
double studentScores = 0, studentAvg = 0, totalAvg = 0;
cout << endl << "Class Statistics" << endl << endl;

while (inputFile >> studentInfo){
    if(count == 0){         //if count == 0, then studentInfo contains the ID
        ++numstudents;      //increment number of students
        cout << "Current Student ID: " << studentInfo << endl;     //output student ID
    }
    else{                   //else, studentInfo contains a quiz score
        studentScores += studentInfo;       //total up cur student quiz scores
    }
    ++count;        //increment counter to keep track of which data your're looking at
    if(count == numquizzes + 1){        //if counter = number of quizzes + 1 for student ID, current student is now complete
        studentAvg = studentScores / numquizzes;    //compute the average for student
        totalAvg += studentAvg;         //add average to total for later class avg calculation
        studentScores = 0;              //reset scores for next student
        cout << "     Student Average: " << studentAvg << endl;     //output current student average
        count = 0;      //reset counter
    }
}
totalAvg = totalAvg/numstudents;        //when all students are evaluated, calc total average
cout << endl << "Class Average: " << totalAvg << endl;
inputFile.close();
return 0;
```

This is a basic way to calculate averages. The code contains comments explaining how it works.

It holds data of one student at a time, computing the average when all of the students data is read, moving on until all students are accounted for.

This is the output for my specified input:

```
Class Statistics

Current Student ID: 123
     Student Average: 5
Current Student ID: 234
     Student Average: 4.25
Current Student ID: 568
     Student Average: 4

Class Average: 4.41667
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while (inputFile >> studentInfo)
{
    cout << "Student " << i << "'s info is " << studentInfo << endl;
    ++i;
}
```

Is this what you were asking?

Edited for OP's comment.  OK:  so you want the info presented to be an average.  So it makes sense (if this is what you want) to store that average.  You can replace that loop on `qz` with this code, to make that happen:

```
    double totalScore = 0.0;
    enum {NUM_QUIZZES = 5};

    //read in 5 quizzes and get the total score
    for (qz = 1; qz < 5; qz++)
    {
        cout << "Enter quiz score " << qz << " ";
        cin >> score;

        totalScore += score;
    }

    //print the average score to a file
    outputFile << " " << totalScore/NUM_QUIZZES << " ";
```

Comment: Closer! Yes, this is doing what I need it to, however I need to figure out how to get it to display averages, not just the score. A sample output of that is

students 1's info: (students id)
students 2's info (1st quiz score)
etc.

Comment: @AceEbert _"how to get it to display averages"_ You'll need to parse the values to build the average from one by one until line ending, and calculate the average for all of them. Then you display the result.

Comment: @WillBriggs No, that wasn't exactly what the OP's asking for, there's more than a single `score` to be read from the file format, where the average should be calculated from per student.

Comment: That is correct, there is more than one score, I've done things like that before, but never in this way. I've researched it a lot but nothing seems to work...

Comment: See above answer for an answer to the averaging question as well.