# C++ Finding the number of times something appears in two elements a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, ifstream

Sorry for the confusing title, not sure how to phrase it.
Basically, I have a vector full of structures consisting of some information on teams that were in the finals of some sport. The structure looks like this:

```
struct Year{
    string year;
    string host;
    string winner;
    string score;
    string runnerUp;
};
```

I have filled the vector with information from a file, and want to find how many times each team played in the finals. This means I need to count the number of times each team was either the winner or the runner up. What is a fairly simple way to go about doing this?
For reference, the file looks like this:

```
Year    Host    Winner  Score   Runner-up
1936    Germany United States   19-8    Canada
1948    United Kingdom  United States   65-21   France
1952    Finland United States   36-25   Soviet Union
1956    Australia   United States   89-55   Soviet Union
1960    Italy   United States   No playoffs Soviet Union
1964    Japan   United States   73-59   Soviet Union
1968    Mexico  United States   65-50   Yugoslavia
1972    West Germany    Soviet Union    51-50   United States
1976    Canada  United States   95-74   Yugoslavia
1980    Soviet Union    Yugoslavia  86-77   Italy
1984    United States   United States   96-65   Spain
1988    South Korea Soviet Union    76-63   Yugoslavia
1992    Spain   United States   117-85  Croatia
1996    United States   United States   95-69   Yugoslavia
2000    Australia   United States   85-75   France
2004    Greece  Argentina   84-69   Italy
2008    China   United States   118-107 Spain
2012    United Kingdom  United States   107-100 Spain
```

Assume the vector has been filled correctly

Comment: Well, you're going to need a loop. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried much yet, not sure where to start. The problem is I need to keep everything very generic so it will work with multiple files. I thought about creating another vector that held the counts, but I'm not sure how to implement it while keeping it sorted correctly.

Comment: @Greesy _"Assume the vector has been filled correctly"_ Your 1st hurdle starts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi, I'd seriously recommend you introduce some reasonable delimiters with your input file format.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ They are delimited with '\t'. I didn't create the file, I just have to work with it. I already have the vector created, and have used it for a few things before this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse your vector and increase a counter for each occurrence of a team. You can encode the counter as a `map<std::string, int>`, where the key is the name of the team.

**Edit**: the ugly cousin of `map`s are vectors of pairs of keys and values. I show you a possible way to define your data types. You can change the `struct` for a `std::pair`, but since I guess this is homework, you may want to stick to simple data types.

```
struct Counter{
    string team;
    int counter;
}

std::vector<Counter> counters;
```

I leave you think about how to design the algorithm for these structures. Hint: `std::find`.

Comment: Though that sounds simple enough, I haven't covered maps yet and would prefer to stay away from them. Thanks though!