# Stringstream won't convert properly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, console-application, stringstream

To begin with, I'm using Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 Express and c++. Don't know which C++ standard I'm using though.

I'm completely new to programming so I might have missed some fundamental part in this function. I am making a 10-question quiz and this one is about when MJ passed away. I'm trying to make sure that the program won't crash if the user inputs something other than an `int` by using `getline()`.

I learned about `stringstream` and to convert. It is supposed to convert "playerAnswer" to an `int`.
I am using`#include <iostream>` `#include <string>` `#include <sstream>`  and `using namespace std;`

```
int question_3()
{

    cout << "Question 3:\n";

    string playerAnswer = "";
    int convertedAnswer = 0;    

    cout << "Which year did Michael Jackson die? 2008, 2009 or 2010?\n" \
            "Your answer: ";

    while (true)
    {
        getline(cin, playerAnswer);
        stringstream convHolder;   // EDIT: Got an answer and it now works.
                                   // Forgot  (playerAnswer) in convHolder
        if (convHolder >> convertedAnswer)
        {
            if (convertedAnswer == 2009)
            {
                cout << endl << "Correct! \nOn August 29 1958 the legend was born. \n" \
                                "On June 25 2009 he passed away in his rented mansion in Holmby Hills.\n";
                cout << endl;
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << endl << "Wrong. \nOn August 29 1958 the legend was born. \n" \
                                "On June 25 2009 he passed away in his rented mansion in Holmby Hills.\n";
                cout << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid number, please try again: ";
        }
    }
}
```

If you could make it work as intended and in a better way/with shorter code I'd be very interested to learn it :) Any input from you guys is appriciated!

/NickL

Comment: _"but this doesn't seem to work"_ is to vague to ask. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing your stringstream to use the string that the user input:

```
stringstream convHolder;
```

should be

```
stringstream convHolder(playerAnswer);
```

Comment: Thank you. Small mistake but just couldn't see it. Now how do I close this question and choose your answer as the solution to the problem?

Comment: @NickL you click the check mark near the arrows/score of my answer