# Move text cursor to new line

Tags: c++

I have a text file, that looks like this:

```
Name_of_st1 67 5  87 4  78 4
Name_of_st2 89 5  56 3  79 4
...
```

I have written a program that reads the data and creates a vector of students with its own vector of subjects. The program reads the first line correctly, but when i ask it to write out name of second student, `std::cout` displays garbage. Here is the code:

```
struct Subject {
    int mark0;
    int mark1;
};
struct Student {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    vector<Subject>my_marks;    
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Subject& sub);
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Student& st);

int main()
try
{

    ifstream ifs("Text.txt");
    vector<Student>group;
    Student s1, s2;
    ifs >> s1;
    group.push_back(s1);
    getline(ifs, temp);
    ifs >> s2;
    group.push_back(s2);
    cout << group.size();
    cout << group[0].name;
    cout << group[0].surname;
    cout << group[1].name;
    cout << group[0].my_marks[1].mark0;

}
catch (exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
catch (...)
{
    cerr << "exception \n";
    return 2;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Subject& sub)
{
    int m0, m1;
    is >> m0; 
    if (!is) return is;
    is>> m1;
    sub.mark0 = m0;
    sub.mark1 = m1;
    return is;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Student& st)
{
        char n1[50];
        char n2[50];
        is >> n1;
        is >> n2;
        strcpy_s(st.name, n1);
        strcpy_s(st.surname, n2);
        if (!is) return is;

            while (true)
            {
                Subject sub;
                if (!(is >> sub)) break;
                st.my_marks.push_back(sub);
            }

    return is;
}
```

I have tried this, but still the same:

```
 string temp
    ifs >> s1;
    getline(ifs, temp);
    group.push_back(s1);
```

And this:

```
char n1[50];
char n2[50];

for (int i = 0;; ++i)
{
    char n0;
    is.get(n0);
    if (isspace(n0)) break;
    n1[i] = n0;
}

for (int i = 0;; ++i)
{
    char n0;
    is.get(n0);
    if (isspace(n0)) break;
    n2[i] = n0;
}
    if (!is) return is;
    strcpy_s(st.name, n1);
    strcpy_s(st.surname, n2);
```

Then i added `':'` after every Name of Student and used `is.get(n1, 100, ':')`.
It still reads the first line correctly, but refuses to read the next. Whatever i did, i can`t move text cursor to the beginning of new line. If anyone can help me, i would appreciate it.

Comment: You might be interested to read [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi), also use `std::string name;` rather than  `char name[50];` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second student is not being read because you put the stream in a bad state reading the first student.

```
if (!(is >> sub)) break;
```

You basically read subjects until the input breaks (which is when you hit a name). Since you don't reset the state of the stream to `good` any further attempts to read will be ignored.

You have two choices.

- Set the state to good after you have finished reading the subjects.
  This has an issue in that you will probably go into a infinite loop as your checking of the stream state is spotty currently.
- Read a line then parse the subject information from the line.

I would go for option 2.

```
 // After you have read the name.
 // The rest of the line is scores. So read a whole line.
 std::string  line;
 std::getline(is, line);

 // convert the line into a stream.
 std::stringstream linestream(line);

 // Now parse the stream for subject.
 Subject sub;
 while(linestream >> sub) {        // Note this reads an item and checks the
                                   // state of the stream. The while body
                                   // is only entered on a successful read.
     st.my_marks.push_back(sub);
 }
```

Comment: @StacyShavliuk: If it now works. I would submit the code at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a more en-depth review of your code.

Comment: Yes, i added just one line is.clear() and now it works. And i feel so supid. But i`m still very grateful to you!