# How to update a single view of listview instead of notifyDataSetChanged in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to update single row of listview which contains a image after certain time of addition to listview. I am using notifyDataSetChanged for this but when other visible views contains a imageView, it gets a jerk felling on other visible imageViews due to notifyDataSetChanged.

Can someone suggest a better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: /OT Here's the code shoppe for your [recently deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776936/how-to-read-this-input-file-in-c) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Amazing...Thank you very much. Sorry I haven't put my question correctly but thanks again

Comment: Do better research, ask better questions in future. Seems you're constantly failing about this here!

Comment: Will definitely improve. Thanks for the feedback. Most of the time I ask question in a hurry, that's why such thing happen. 
Will not happen again in future. That's my assurance

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the imageview when you create/update it in the adapter. You can then change the image later on. However, since list items get recycled, you will want to set a tag on it with some id of the content so that you make sure you're still updating the right item.

Comment: The problem is when user scroll up and this view becomes invisible..and after some time when user scroll down and the view becomes visible again, how do we handle this scenerio?

Comment: Well you must be storing the data that backs the list somewhere, no? So once you hit that "Certain time," just update your data know that the image has already been updated, and go straight into loading the new image.