# Splitting a getline() string into multiple int and char variables?

Tags: c++, string, getline

I'm having some trouble understanding how to properly manipulate strings. The program below is a simple calculator.

When I put the input directly into variables through multiple cin statements, everything worked fine. Now, I want to take the input as a string with getline() and store the numbers/operators in existing variables from the getline().

My main issue is that I want the program to recognize both `2+2` and `2 + 2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Num1, Num2, Num3 = 0, result;
    char Operator1, Operator2 = 0;
    string input, in1;

    cout << "Enter your equation on one line.\n";
    getline(cin, input);


    //this is where getline needs to be manipulated into Num1/2/3 and Operator1/2

    cout << input;


    if (Operator2 != 0)
    {
        if (Operator1 == '+')
        {
            if (Operator2 == '+')
            {
                result = Num1 + Num2 + Num3;
                cout << "I made it to A!";
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '-')
            {
                result = Num1 + Num2 - Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '/')
            {
                result = Num1 + Num2 / Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '*')
            {
                result = Num1 + Num2 * Num3;
            }
        }
        else if (Operator1 == '-')
        {
            if (Operator2 == '+')
            {
                result = Num1 - Num2 + Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '-')
            {
                result = Num1 - Num2 - Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '/')
            {
                result = Num1 - Num2 / Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '*')
            {
                result = Num1 - Num2 * Num3;
            }
        }
        else if (Operator1 == '/')
        {
            if (Operator2 == '+')
            {
                result = Num1 / Num2 + Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '-')
            {
                result = Num1 / Num2 - Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '/')
            {
                result = Num1 / Num2 / Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '*')
            {
                result = Num1 / Num2 * Num3;
            }
        }
        else if (Operator1 == '*')
        {
            if (Operator2 == '+')
            {
                result = Num1 * Num2 + Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '-')
            {
                result = Num1 * Num2 - Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '/')
            {
                result = Num1 * Num2 / Num3;
            }
            else if (Operator2 == '*')
            {
                result = Num1 * Num2 * Num3;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I don't recognize that operator. Did you type in one of these?: + - * /";
        }
    }
    else if (Operator2 == 0)
    {
        if (Operator1 == '+')
    {
            result = Num1 + Num2;
    }
        else if (Operator1 == '-')
    {
            result = Num1 - Num2;
    }
        else if (Operator1 == '*')
    {
            result = Num1 * Num2;
    }
        else if (Operator1 == '/')
    {
            result = Num1 / Num2;
    }
        else
    {
        cout << "I don't recognize that operator. Did you type in one of these?: + - * /";
    }

        result = Num1 + Num2;
        cout << "I made it to B!";
    }


    cout << "Your result is: " << result << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, but I'd much prefer an explanation to working code.

I'm not interested in the math logic or `using namespace std` aspects of the program.

Comment: Also, please ignore the cout << "I Made it to x!"

Those were some tests I forgot to take out.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) are some hints to make your life easier. Use `std::istringstream `.

Comment: Will operation always be a single character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should ask yourself whether it is necessary to store the entire string, instead of just using `cin` on the variables directly, as you said you did previously.

If you really do want to store the entire string (as you do now for echoing it), you could consider using a stringstream (you're already including `sstream` in your file, for some reason):

```
getline(cin, input);

std::istringstream iss(input);
// you can now use iss just as cin.
// I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but it would look something like this:
iss >> num1;
iss >> Operator1;
iss >> num2;

cout << input;
```

Comment: Awesome! Stringstream seems to be exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @DoubleLlama Just `std::istringstream` is sufficient, `std::stringstream` has it's oddities.