# Write full name in one input on a file

Tags: c++

I want to write full name on a text file in c++. For example- I want to write "John Henry Ford" in one input in C++ using fstream, ifstream, and ofstream.

Comment: And what's your question? It's simple like that: `of << "John Henry Ford" ;`

Comment: Or do you have a problem like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)?

Comment: your question is wague

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file("test.txt");
    file << "John Henry Ford";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```