# How to read from a file to constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, file, constructor

I have a players.txt file where I need to read from and put my readings in a constructor and then I will make a list of these TennisPlayer objects. And I am stuck with how to do it. Well, the first thing is I read from file word by word or line by line but couldn't manage how to put my readings into constructor.
My constructor has five inputs:

```
TennisPlayer(string firstName, tring lastName, int ranking, int totalPoints, string country)
```

And part of my players.txt file is here:

```
Novak Djokovic 16790 Serbia
Andy Murray 8945 Great Britain
```

And secondly, how can take "Great Britain" as one string?

I am really new in C++ and in a desperate position. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does the file reading code look like?  What didn't work as you expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does reading a record struct fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: Hint 1 - I think you would do better to not try to put readings into your structure (but this can be done).  Instead, construct an empty object, then tell that structure to read its contents from the file ... ctors can not return errors.  IMHO, a method can more easily handle file i/o errors

Comment: You misspelled string on the second argument and your sample input only has 1 numeric field, but your constructor requites 2. 
We need to see the code you have written so far.
Regarding Great Britain - if you have control over the format of the input (i.e. it's your own design) you could put quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stream from a file and then pass it to a class like this. It will iterate over the file, store the values in a vector and then initialise a vector of those objects in the constructor. To read the country, we keep reading in words until we find the end of the line. Therefore, I am working under the assumption that each tennis player is specified in a single line.

Note that there is no error checking here, you may wish to add that

```
    class TennisPlayersList
    {
    public:
        struct TennisPlayer
        {
            std::string first_name;
            std::string second_name;
            int ranking;
            int total_points;
            std::string country;
        };

        TennisPlayersList(std::istream& filestream)
            :players(ReadPlayersFromFile(filestream))
        {}
    private:
        std::vector<TennisPlayer> players;

        static std::vector<TennisPlayer> ReadPlayersFromFile(std::istream& filestream)
        {
            std::vector<TennisPlayer> p;
            while (filestream.eof() == false)
            {
                p.push_back(ReadPlayer(filestream));
            }
            return p;
        }

        static TennisPlayer ReadPlayer(std::istream& filestream)
        {
            using namespace std;
            TennisPlayer player;
            std::string line;
            getline(filestream, line);

            std::stringstream ss(line);

            ss >> player.first_name;
            ss >> player.second_name;
            ss >> player.ranking;
            ss >> player.total_points;

            // country could be several words, keep appending until we have finished
            while (ss.good())
            {
                std::string country_part;
                ss >> country_part;
                if (player.country.empty())
                    player.country += country_part;
                else 
                    player.country += " " + country_part;
            }
            return player;
        }
    };
```

call with something like this

```
std::fstream players;
players.open("tennis_players.txt", std::ios::in);
TennisPlayersLists list(players);
players.close();
```