# How does cin differentiate between a space and newline?

Tags: c++

I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    int n;
    if(input=="hi"){
        cin >> n;
    }

    cout<< n;

    return 0;
}
```

Let's restrict the value of input to be "hi" for this case. If I give the input as

**hi 20**

Output is:
**20**

If I give the input as

**hi**

**20**

Output is:
**20**

How does the cin differentiate between space and newline and correctly take the value of n in both cases ?

Comment: Both space and newline are categorized as whitespace.  Streaming like done in the example will skip whitespace sequences.

Comment: How does it differentiate? The point is that it doesn't differentiate between spaces and newlines.

Comment: You can provide the stream with a facet that has your own notion of what is considered "whitespace".  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806891/getline-to-read-in-a-string-that-has-both-white-spaces-and-is-comma-seperated/35807462#35807462

Comment: Note that `std::cin` just provides a stream of characters. It doesn't analyze them at all. It's the `operator>>` that cares about whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't.

If you need different behaviour, you should use `std::getline`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline