# Getting bus error and weird outputs when trying to print arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Excuse my amateur knowledge of C++, but I have an assignment for a class where I have to grab data from a city.dat file and sort it into arrays. I must then print the data to the console.

When I run my code, I get either a "Segmentation fault: 11" or a long string of random characters (containing what I want to print) and then a "Bus error: 10".

Here is a pastebin of my code:

```
/**
 *  @file cities_2_landon_haugh.cpp
 *  
 *  @brief Reads data from a datafile, sorts it, and prints it in the terminal in
 *      in a readable format.
 *
 *  @author Landon Haugh (landonh12)
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct CITYDATA {

    string cityname[0];
    string pop1[0];
    string pop2[0];
    string pop3[0];
    string pop4[0];
    string temp[0];
    string rain[0];

};

CITYDATA *data = new CITYDATA();

void readDataFile();
void sortData();
void printData();

string input[0];

int main() {

    readDataFile();
    sortData();
    printData();

    return 0;

}

/**
 *  This function reads a data file and adds its elements to an array.
 *
 *  @param None.
 *  @return Void.
 */
void readDataFile() {

    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("city.dat");

    int i = -1;

    while(true) {

        i = i + 1;
        if(fin.fail()) break;   
        fin >> input[i];                        

    }

    fin.close();

}

void sortData() {


    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]); i++) {

        j = j + 1;

        if(j == 7) {
            j = 0;
            k = k + 1;
        }

        if(j == 0) {
            data->cityname[k] = input[i];
        } if(j == 1) {
            data->pop1[k] = input[i];
        } if(j == 2) {
            data->pop2[k] = input[i];
        } if(j == 3) {
            data->pop3[k] = input[i];
        } if(j == 4) {
            data->pop4[k] = input[i];
        } if(j == 5) {
            data->temp[k] = input[i];
        } if(j == 6) {
            data->rain[k] = input[i];
        }

    }


}


void printData() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        cout << data->cityname[i];
        cout << data->pop1[i];
        cout << data->pop2[i];
        cout << data->pop3[i];
        cout << data->pop4[i];
        cout << data->temp[i];
        cout << data->rain[i];

    }

}
```

This is after I tried to create an instance of CITYDATA with a pointer.

Here is the contents of the city.dat file:

```
Biloxi 50000 52000 35000 44054 69 52 
Jackson 165000 168000 170000 172638 64 60 
Meridian 37000 38000 32000 40921 61 50 
Picayune 8000 9000 8500 10813 66 70 
Gulfport 80000 90000 110000 71012 69 55
```

Comment: Please post your code here with a [mcve], instead of providing a link to it.

Comment: Making arrays with length 0 and indexing them with who knows how many items. I kinda see a problem there...

Comment: _@Landon_ _`string cityname[0];`_ Huh?? Did you mean `string cityname;` simply? Don't confuse `std::string` with `char[]` arrays. Also shouldn't the other variables like `pop1` etc rather simply `int` or `double` values?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, I am trying to make an array of strings. I planned on converting the strings to double's and int's later. Should I use char[] instead?

Comment: @LandonHaugh _"Well, I am trying to make an array of strings."_ Why not making an array of `CITYDATA` instead? Or even better a `std::vector<CITYDATA>`, or more convenient for search options e.g.`std::map<std::string,CITYDATA>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how would I populate an array of CITYDATA in this program?

Comment: @LandonHaugh Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) leads you to an idea how to do that. It's not exactly talking about the problem you seem to have, but still generic enough to lead you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use an array, you can populate it like:

```
#define MAXIMUM_CITIES (5)

CityData tokyo;
CityData data_for_cities[MAXIMUM_CITIES];
// Example of "populating"
data_for_cities[0] = tokyo;
```

Reading data from a file has already been covered by [searching for "StackOverflow c++ read struct from file"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+struct+from+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Also search the internet for "c++ populate array".

I recommend that you overload `operator>>` to read in an instance of `CityData`.
Your input loop (populating the array from a text file) would look something like this:

```
CityData datum;
CityData data_for_cities[MAXIMUM_CITIES];
unsigned int index = 0U;
while (input_file >> datum)
{
  if (index < MAXIMUM_CITIES)
  {
    data_for_cities[index] = datum;
    ++index;
  }
}
```