# c++ discrepancy between tellg and getline

Tags: c++, input, mingw, ifstream

In my project, there are multiple lines of input and I am getting a strange bug where after the first line, the ifstream cuts off characters based on how far away it is from the end of the file. (If there are 3 lines, line 1 is fine. line 2 is missing the first 2 chars from the line. Line 3 is missing 1 char from the line.)

**An example of input/output:**

input:

```
John Smith
Jane Doe
Donald Trump
```

output:

```
whole line:John Smith*
What's in the stream?:John Smith.
        Next line...
whole line:Jane Doe*
What's in the stream?:ne Doe.
        Next line...
whole line:Donald Trump*
What's in the stream?:onald Trump.
```

**Code:**

Input1 function:

```
void input1(ifstream& in, LinkedList &linList)
{

    string wholeLine;
    int len = in.tellg();
    while(getline(in,wholeLine)){
        in.seekg(len);
        string name;
        vector<double> xArr;
        vector<double> yArr;

        cout << "whole line:" << wholeLine << "." << endl;

        string streamCheck;
        int tempLocForCheck = in.tellg();
        getline(in,streamCheck);
        in.seekg(tempLocForCheck);
        cout << "What's in the stream?:" << streamCheck << "." << endl;

        name = getName(wholeLine);    //Call to getName function

        string throwAway;
        getline(in,throwAway);
        cout << "\t\tNext line..." << endl;

        len = in.tellg();
    }
}
```

getName function:

```
string getName(string inName){
    stringstream in(inName);

    string name = "";
    bool notNumber = true;
    while(in.peek() != '\n' && notNumber){
        string letter(1,in.peek());
        if(regex_match(letter ,regex("^[A-Za-z\\s]+$"))){
            name += in.get();
        }
        else{
            notNumber = false;
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Of course, this code has been simplified to the point where anything that doesn't touch the ifstream has been excluded. I tested the code as is and the problem still persists.

I have the `throwAway` at the bottom because in the actual use of the code, I will have extraneous data at the end of the line.

As you can see, it seems like the `tellg()` is returning a different value than what the `getline()` would have you expect. According to the `getline()` we are at the beginning of the line. However, according to the `tellg()` we are not at the beginning of the line.

I would really appreciate any help with this. I'm sorry there is a lot of code to read through. I did my best to slim it down. I have been fiddling with it for hours trying to fix it but haven't been able to. Thanks.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am required to use the  MinGW 4.9.2 compiler.

Comment: The line endings may be `\r\n` on a windows system. That could explain the difference. Inspect your input file with a hex-editor to confirm that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ After inspecting the input in notepad++, it shows that the lines are ending with CRLF. How does this effect my program?

Comment: I don't get why you are using `tellg()` here at all? What is the purpose?

Comment: I need to have the entire ifstream for the rest of the function. so I `seekg()` after I get the whole line so I can use the ifstream to grab numbers on the rest of the line. I omitted that because the problem was still happening without the other data on the line. The actual input data will look like `John Smith -23,54.6 12,3 6,1 -23,54.6`. I need the ifstream at the beginning of the line so I can save these numbers into `xArr` and `yArr` respectively.

Comment: There a loads of easier ways to do this.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it) for instance. You overcomplicate your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for the suggestions. I was unaware that you could still extract doubles from stringstreams. Your suggestions of avoiding `tellg()` and `seekg()` were great. It was off because of the line endings. After switching to a stringstream, it was a lot easier and it works without any bugs. 

Thank you.