# Reading multiple data types from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, text, fstream, ifstream

I have the following contents in a text file.

> ```
> Waterpark Avenue 3000
> Coit 1010
> Synergy Park 9119
> Joaquin 1980
> Richardson 2413
> ```

I want to read the file in such a way that I can output the details in different columns using setw() operator. 
The issue I'm facing here is that some lines have 2 names and the others have just 1 and, I can't figure out a way to get around it.

Comment: Check if this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably start by reading an entire line into a string. Then I'd search for the first non-digit, starting from the right end of the string. Or, depending, I might search for the first white-space character starting from the right end of the string (the two seem equivalent in your examples).

Either way, once you've found that point, you can create one string from the beginning to there, and another from there to the end.

Comment: Could you give me an example code for searching for the first white space from the right and creating a new string. 
The issue is I'm restricted to using the stuff I've been taught in class but she just covered reading either just a string or a number from the file.

Comment: @AshwinNishad useful standard functions are [`find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of), [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), and [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) Edit: and [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: If it's for a class project and you can't use certain things, you can always fall back to a for loop to scan the string from the end.