# C++ import delimited file to vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to import the data shown below into vectors so I can do some simple operations on them and plot them eventually. I used getline() to skip the first line, then I could import all the columns successfully into float vectors except the first one, because it contains a string. Is there a way to import this column into a float vector and instruct it somehow to replace NRM with 0 every time it's imported?

```
STEP  Xc (Am2)  Yc (Am2)  Zc (Am2)  MAG(A/m)   Dg    Ig    Dsp    Isp   a95
NRM  -1.67E-10  3.83E-09  9.71E-10  3.60E-04   2.5  14.2   2.5  14.2  0.0 
2    -1.51E-09  3.16E-09  2.53E-08  2.32E-03 115.6  82.1 115.6  82.1  0.0 
5    -6.57E-08 -4.05E-08  8.64E-07  7.89E-02 211.7  84.9 211.7  84.9  0.0 
7    -1.34E-07 -5.45E-08  1.65E-06  1.50E-01 202.2  85.0 202.2  85.0  0.0
```

The code I used to import the data looks something like this:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream theFile("spam.txt");

    string dummy;
    float column1;
    float column2;
    float column3;
    float column4;
    float column5;
    float column6;
    float column7;
    float column8;
    float column9;
    float column10;

    vector<float>stp;
    vector<float>mag;
    vector<float>dsp;
    vector<float>isp;

    getline(theFile, dummy);

    while(theFile >> column1 >> column2 >> column3 >> column4 >> column5 >> 
    column6 >> column7 >> column8 >> column9 >> column10)
    {
       stp.push_back(column1); **// doesn't work//**
       mag.push_back(column5);
       dsp.push_back(column8);
       isp.push_back(column9);
    }
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: Since the first column can be something other than a number you need to read it as a string, and try to convert it to a number and check if this conversion was successful.

Comment: On a more design-related note, it seems to be that you should have a single structure containing `stp`, `mag`, `dsp` and `isp` members (as discrete values), and then have a single vector of that structure.

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it) please. I believe you can get further from there.

Comment: how do I read a specific column as a string? I thought you have to read the whole file line by line first. I just started to learn C++ so I'm not sure how structures work, I'll research it.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ thanks for the useful links! I think I fixed my problem but I'll read them anyway after work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd read in the value of the first column in a string first and - if it is different from `"NRM"`, convert it to a float. BTW—as mentioned in the comments—you could think of defining a structure that takes over a complete record, and then use a vector of such structure objects.

```
std::string column1str;
while(theFile >> column1str >> column2 >> column3 >> column4 >> column5 >> 
    column6 >> column7 >> column8 >> column9 >> column10)
{
  if (column1str == "NRM") {
     column1 = 0.0;
  }
  else {
     try {
         column1 = std::stof(column1str);
     } catch( ... )
     {
       std::cout << "invalid value for column1: " << column1str << std::endl;
       column1 = 0.0;
     }
  }
  // proceed as you like; probably encapsulate values in a struct....
}
```