# C++ How to load a textfile and adding the content to a class?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn how to use classes and I figured I'd create some sort of supermarket system to aid me with learning. After I have saved all the values from my text file into the temp variables, how do I then use them to create an object? I assume I want one object per item you can "buy"?

If you have any other tips on how to improve my code, please mention them as I just started with C++ a few days ago.

My text file looks like:

```
42 68 Apples
35 1 Oranges
70 25 Bananas
```

And my code is below:

```
// Classes.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class Products {
private:
    int price;
    int ID;
    int quantity;

public:
    void setPrice(int newPrice) {
        price = newPrice;
    }
    void setID(int newID) {
        ID = newID;
    }
    void setQuantity(int newQuantity) {
        quantity = newQuantity;
    }

    int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

};


int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::string input;
    std::string temp;
    std::string temp2;
    std::string temp3;

    int counter = 0;
    while (input != "e" && input != "r") {
        std::cout << "Do you want to (r)ead the inventory or (e)dit it? (input 'r' or 'e'): ";
        getline(std::cin, input);
    }
    if (input == "r") {
        std::ifstream pFile ("products.txt");
        if (pFile.is_open()) {
            while (getline(pFile, line)) {
                std::istringstream iss(line);
                iss >> temp >> temp2 >> temp3;
                counter++;


            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Just some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: Create an object, and set each of the private variables in the class with the temps. In the next loop iteration, the temps will be reread and the process redone

Comment: But if I do something like


    Product test;
    test.setID = temp;

etc, won't it get overwritten after every loop?

Comment: @Jdoe You would save a copy to a `std::vector<Product>`.

Comment: Genius. Thanks a lot all of you.

Btw, was there anything wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the text file that you are using as an example and trying to populate a set of classes with the information I'd do something like this:

**Text File**

> ```
> 42 68 Apples
> 35 1 Oranges
> 70 25 Bananas
> ```

Looking at the text file you have an `int` followed by `space` then another `int` followed by another `space` finally followed by a `varying size of char[]`. We can use this information to create your `class` or `struct` and this is how I would create the `class` based off of the content from the file that is being read in or parsed.

**Produce.h**

```
#ifndef PRODUCE_H
#define PRODUCE_H

#include <string>

class Produce {
private:
    unsigned price_;   // Normally would use float but will use unsigned for simplicity
    unsigned quantity_;
    std::string name_; // You could use the int as an id as you were using

public:
    Produce() {} // Default Constructor

    ~Produce() {} // Default Destructor

                  // User Constructor
    Produce(const std::string& name, const unsigned& price, const unsigned& qty )
        : name_(name), price_(price), quantity_( qty ) {}

    // Copy By Const Reference Constructor
    Produce(const Produce& other) {
        name_     = other.name_;
        price_    = other.price_;
        quantity_ = other.quantity_;
    }

    // Assignment Operator
    Produce& operator=(const Produce& other) {
        name_     = other.name_;
        price_    = other.price_;
        quantity_ = other.quantity_;
        return *this;
    }

    // Setters & Getters
    void setOrChangePrice(const unsigned& priceChange) {
        price_ = priceChange;
    }
    unsigned getPrice() const { return price_; }

    void setName(const std::string& name) {
        // Already Has A Name? Return!
        if (!name_.empty())
            return;
    }
    std::string getName() const { return name_; }

    void setOrChangeQuantity(const unsigned& qty) {
        quantity_ = qty;
    }
    unsigned getQuantity() const {
        return quantity_;
    }

};

#endif // PRODUCE_H
```

**Produce.cpp**

```
#include "Produce.h"

// Normally Constructor(s) & Function Definitions Would Go Here
// Since this is a simple class; I declared & defined them in the header.
```

**Inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include <vector>

#include "Produce.h"

class Inventory {
private:
    std::vector<Produce>  produce_;

public:
    Inventory() {}
    ~Inventory() {
        if (!produce_.empty()) {
            produce_.clear();
        }
    }

    std::vector<Produce> getProduceList() const {
        return produce_;
    }

    unsigned getProduceListSize() const {
        return static_cast<unsigned>( produce_.size() );
    }

    void addProduce(const Produce& produce) {
        produce_.push_back(produce);
    }

    Produce getProduce(const std::string& name) const {
        for (unsigned n = 0; n < produce_.size(); ++n) {
            if (name == produce_[n].getName()) {
                return produce_[n];
            } else {
                return Produce();
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned getPrice(const std::string& name) const {
        for (unsigned n = 0; n < produce_.size(); ++n) {
            if (name == produce_[n].getName()) {
                return produce_[n].getPrice();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned getQuantity( const std::string& name ) const {
        for (unsigned n = 0; n < produce_.size(); ++n) {
            if (name == produce_[n].getName()) {
                return produce_[n].getQuantity();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }   
};

#endif // INVENTORY_H
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"
```

**Main.cpp**

```
// #include <vector> // Also Included In Inventory.h
// #include <string>    // Also Included In Produce.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// #include "Produce.h"  // Also Included In Inventory.h
#include "Inventory.h"

int main( ) {
    // Same As Your Text File
    std::string strFilename("ProduceInventory.txt");    
    std::ifstream fileIn;

    // Temps
    unsigned price = 0;
    unsigned qty   = 0;
    std::string name;

    Inventory inventory;

    fileIn.open(strFilename.c_str());
    if (!fileIn.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Can not read file\n";
    }

    while (fileIn >> price >> qty >> name) {
        Produce produce(name, price, qty);
        inventory.addProduce(produce);
    } 

    if ( fileIn.is_open() ) {
        fileIn.close();
    }

    // Test Our Inventory From File
    for (unsigned n = 0; n < inventory.getProduceListSize(); n++) {
        std::cout << "Name: " << inventory.getProduceList()[n].getName() << " "
        << "Price: " << inventory.getProduceList()[n].getPrice() << " "
        << "Qty: " << inventory.getProduceList()[n].getQuantity() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Check To See If Our Search Method Works
    std::cout << "Enter a product type by name to get its price and qty on hand.\n";
    name.clear(); // reuse
    std::cin >> name;

    Produce p = inventory.getProduce(name);
    if (p.getName().empty()) {
        std::cout << "We either do not carry this produce or we are out of stock\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Our price is " << p.getPrice() << " and we have " << p.getQuantity() << " on hand\n";
        // Or
        std::cout << "Our price is " << inventory.getPrice(name) << " and we have " << inventory.getQuantity(name) << " on hand\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now this is just one of many ways this can be done; but also make sure that your text file is in the appropriate location of the working directory for your IDE or that you specify the correct path along with the filename and extension to be able to open and read from the file in the first place.

Much of this code can be fined even more; but I was showing how to use the `std::vector<T>` container and some of its functions and how to iterate through them and to retrieve its data. This is a basic way of parsing a simple text file when you know the exact format of the text file and for each and every line you will have the same data types in the same order.

This will not work for every kind of file parsing because it depends on the file's format. For example another file might have different kind of data from one line to the next and might have keywords or tags to give a description of what kind of data is coming next. For that kind of parsing you would have to read the entire line in first into a string stream then you would have to be able to parse that string stream via tokens to extract the data. Some times parsing a file might have multiple lines that belong to a data set and for that you would have to parse by chunks or blobs.

Parsing text files is harder to parse than binary file formats because you have to check each line and character of the text and you also have to be cautious 
of character returns, new line characters etc. With binary format you just have to know how many bytes to read in and what type of data it is expected to be. There are many books that are written on just this topic alone on how to parse data from a file. There is no one simple way that fits all.