# Read data from a file

Tags: c++, file-handling

The file has data in this form.

> ```
> 1#Ali Khan#Lahore#M#22#1#1#1997#1
> 2#Ahsan Latif#Karachi#M#19#21#5#1996#1
> 3#M Sultan#Lahore#M#15#15#1#1998#1
> 4#Sana Ali#Islamabad#F#19#3#4#1996#1
> ```

Where each line represents a unique user in following order (Id, Name, City, Gender, Age, DoB).
My program will have to read this file line by line, and populate the users list.

```
void loadUsersfromFile( facebookUser * userlist, int & size);
```

`facebookUser` is a `struct`. And `userlist` is an array

I have tried using `getline()` and put a line in a string variable. Then using substr i extract id,username gender etc.
But the problem is that string cannot be copied into facebookUser type array. So it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct mDate {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
struct facebookUser {
    int id;
    char *userName;
    char *city;
    char gender;
    mDate Dob;
    int *friendList;            //Array of int type, where you will store friend id’s
    int friends = 20;           //Store Number of Friends, default value i 20.
    bool active;                // true for active users and false for inactive
};
void loadUsersfromFile (facebookUser * ul, int &s)
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open ("users.txt");
    myFile.close ();
}

int main ()
{
    facebookUser *userlist;
    int size;
    size = 4;
    userlist = new facebookUser[50];
    loadUsersfromFile (userlist, size);
}
```

Comment: Unless your exercise is about dynamic allocation and pointers, then don't do it yourself. Use `std::string` for strings, and `std::vector` for "dynamic arrays". And if you have an array with a size known at compile-time then you should probably use `std::array` (or plain simple arrays) instead.

Comment: You posted a lot of irrelevant code but you haven't posted the code that isn't working. How are we supposed to help you with your code if you don't post it?

Comment: I am asking how can i read this data into array?

Comment: So post the code you wrote to do this, and we'll help you with it. This isn't a web site where people write code for you. Show the code you wrote first.

Comment: @usmansiddique First of all: Don't use raw arrays in c++, use `std::vector<facebookUser>` instead. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) you'll find some ideas how to do that correctly.

Comment: Before you can read anything into `userName, city or friendList` members, you will need to allocate storage for them as well. To help us help you, you need to tell us whether you really want C-style allocation of storage for everything (just using `new`) or can you use containers like `vector` and `string` from C++ -- that will make your life a lot easier and less error prone?

Comment: I have not learnt vectors yet. So yes just using new.

Comment: @usmansiddique _"I have not learnt vectors yet."_ I still cannot believe why really advanced stuff like using the likely error prone stuff like manual memory management using `new` and `delete` is taught in c++ classes before teaching the usual stuff like usage of standard containers and dynamic memory management facilities. All of these teachers must be either sadists, complete idiots, or simply incompetent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would highly recommend **not** to use **char *** in this case. Its not at all required. Instead, use `std::string`.

Like this:

```
struct facebookUser {
    int id;
    std::string userName;
    std::string city;
    char gender;
    mDate Dob;
    int *friendList;            //Array of int type, where you will store friend id’s
    int friends = 20;           //Store Number of Friends, default value i 20.
    bool active;                // true for active users and false for inactive
};
```

Now, use std::getline to get the data.

```
void loadUsersfromFile (facebookUser * ul, int &s)
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open ("users.txt");

    unsigned int userIndex = 0;

    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(myFile, line)) {
            std::istringstream sstr(line);
            std::string value;
            unsigned int columnIndex = 0;

            while (getline(sstr, value, '#')) {
                switch (columnIndex) {
                    case 0: {
                        ul[userIndex].id = stoi(value);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 1: {
                        ul[userIndex].userName = value;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 2: {
                        ul[userIndex].city = value;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 3: {
                        ul[userIndex].gender = value[0];
                    }
                    break;

                    case 4: {
                        ul[userIndex].Dob.day = stoi(value);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 5: {
                        ul[userIndex].Dob.month = stoi(value);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 6: {
                        ul[userIndex].Dob.year = stoi(value);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 7: {
                        ul[userIndex].active = (value == "1") ? true : false;
                    }
                    break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                columnIndex++;
            }

            userIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Suggestion**:

Never use raw pointers in your code unless it is really necessary. In your case, you may replace `int *`, `facebookuser *` with `std::vector` equivalents and `char *` with std::string.