# Assigning variables from file with delimiters

Tags: c++, boost, ifstream

I have a file map.txt:

```
Montreal|Quebec,Toronto|30,40
New York|Boston,Philadelphia,Scranton|20,10,50
```

I want to assign the first part before the "|" to cityString, the second part to edgesString and the third part to costString. Then, I will use boost to split the strings into corresponding vectors, and assign these vectors to a custom CityNode Object.

This is my code:

```
string cityString;
string edgesString;
string costString;
vector<string> edgesVector;
vector<string> costVector;
vector<CityNode> cities;
int i = 0;
bool used = true;
string line;
ifstream myfile(this->fileName);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        cout << cityString << "|" << edgesString << "|" << costString << "\n";    // read line of file

        boost::split(edgesVector, edgesString, [](char c) {return c == ','; });    //split edgesString into vector delimiter: ','
        boost::split(costVector, costString, [](char c) {return c == ','; });    // split costString into vector delimiter: ','


        //ASSIGN VARIABLES
        cities[i].setValues(cityString, edgesVector, costVector);
        i++;
    }

    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Incorrect file format";
return cities;
```

when I call

```
 cout << cities[0].getName();
```

I get

```
||
||
```

instead of "Montreal" as I want. I think the error is the way I read the variables from the file but I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: *Then, I will use boost to split the strings into corresponding vectors, and assign these vectors to a custom CityNode Object.* – why? what do you do with those values?

Comment: *cout << cityString << "|" << edgesString << "|" << costString << "\n";    // read line of file* does not do what your comment says it does.

Comment: @NathanOliver you're right. I'm quite new to c++ so I'm not acquainted with proper cout and ifstream syntax. Could you help me fix it?

Comment: @Swordfish its a board game project where each CityNode holds it's city name, a vector of it's edges with neighboring cities and the cost to travel between cities

Comment: Well, you can use `boost::split` to split line by `|`.  Then split each of those sections it gives you.

Comment: @NathanOliver no need for boost there.

Comment: @Swordfish Why not?  They are already using it to split the sub parts so why not use it to generate the sub parts?

Comment: @NathanOliver cause there's no need to require boost at all for that task.

Comment: @Swordfish edgesString is a string. I need to pass each subpart of that string delimited by "," to a vector that holds all the adjacent cities. The use of boost is not to solve my issue, but rather part2 of my project

Comment: @HassanG I think my [_"half baked"_ canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) has some relevant approaches and techniques in the answers.

Comment: @HassanG Basically use `std::getline()` to read a line from the file, then use `std::getline()` with the `'|'` delimiter character to split the string from a `std::istringstream` and drill down further using other delimiter characters. Doesn't look that using boost is necessary to do that at all.

Comment: I removed "Cpp" from the title. "Cpp" is ambiguous; it refers to the C preprocessor. "C++" is the name of the language, but you've already specified the language by using the "c++" tag. (`.cpp` is a common file extension for C++ source, but only because using "+" in file name can cause problems on some systems.)

Comment: You wrote `cout` when you wanted to use `cin`. `cout` prints, `cin` reads. At least I assume that, your usage of `getline` does not fit here. `getline` puts the content of the current line into your variable `line`, which you then do not use. You want to use one of those - `getline` works for files, `cin` creates a prompt for the user. I recommend that you reread some tutorial on what of those you want to do and *slowly* extend it step by step in the direction you want to go. By the way, my approach would be to write a constructor `CityNode(const string& line)`, but do that later.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```
string edgesString;
string costString;
string line;
vector<string> edgesVector;
vector<string> costVector;
vector<CityNode> cities;

ifstream myfile(this->fileName);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        getline(iss, cityString, "|");
        getline(iss, edgesString, "|");
        getline(iss, costString);

        cout << cityString << "|" << edgesString << "|" << costString << "\n"; // display line from file

        auto onComma = [](char c){ return c == ','; };
        boost::split(edgesVector, edgesString, onComma); //split edgesString into vector delimiter: ','
        boost::split(costVector, costString, onComma); // split costString into vector delimiter: ','

        //ASSIGN VARIABLES
        CityNode city;
        city.setValues(cityString, edgesVector, costVector);
        cities.push_back(city);
    }

    myfile.close();
}
else
    cout << "Cannot open file";

return cities;
```

Answer (score -1):

So for what i understand, there is multiple things here :
First the actual content of your file is stored into the `line` variable.
This variable seems to be never used after. Hence, your vectors are not set.

Then the output on the console is the result of the 'cout << cityString << "|" << edgesString << "|" << costString << "\n";` statement, since you never affect any value to those variables they are "empty strings". And because there is 2 line in your file, with the while statement you end up with :

```
||
||
```

Also I think you can split without using boost.

with this code you have the proper output :

```
boost::split(lineVect, line,[](char c) { return c == '|'; });

cout << lineVect[0] << "|" << lineVect[1] << "|" << lineVect[2] << "\n";    

boost::split(edgesVector, lineVect[1], [](char c) { return c == ','; });    //split edgesString into vector delimiter: ','
boost::split(costVector, lineVect[2], [](char c) { return c == ','; });    // split costString into vector delimiter: ','

//ASSIGN VARIABLES
cities[i].setValues(lineVect[0], edgesVector, costVector);
i++;
```