# constructor does not work correctly while reading variables from txt file

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, overloading

I have a issue about my constructor is not correctly working. Whenever i run the program, my overloaded operator might not be perform correctly because i always get the default constructor values when i get the output with **cout**.

I believe that i made my constructor declarations well but all of my objects getting filled with ***0*** and ***Unknown***

here is my txt file:

```
1 Prince Heins 25
2 Lady Bridgette 29
3 Tony Ann 223
4 Lucy Phoenix 35
```

Here is my code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <ostream>

    using namespace std;
    
    class contact{
    private:
    
        int listno;
        string name;
        string surname;
        string phonenumber;
            
    public:
        contact(){
            this->name="Unknown";
            this->surname="Unknown";
            this->phonenumber="Unknown";
            this->listno=0;
        }
        contact (string name,string surname,string phonenumber){
            this->name=name;
            this->surname=surname;
            this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
        }
        contact(int listno,string name,string surname,string phonenumber){
            
            this->name=name;
            this->surname=surname;
            this->listno=listno;
            this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
        }
    
        friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const contact &con){
            out << con.listno << con.name << con.surname << con.phonenumber;
            return out;
        }
        
        friend istream & operator>> (istream &in, contact &con){
            in >> con.listno >> con.name >> con.surname >> con.phonenumber;
            return in;
        } 
    
    };
    
    
    
    
    
    int main(){
        ifstream pbin("phoneData2.txt");
        string line;
        long linecount;
        for(linecount=0;getline(pbin,line);linecount++);
        contact* myArray = new contact[linecount];
        pbin.seekg(0);
        if(pbin.is_open()){
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<linecount;i++){
                if(pbin!=NULL){
                    while(pbin>>myArray[i]);
                }
                
        }
        pbin.close();
        
        cout << myArray[2]; // try attempt
        
        return 0;
        }
    }
```

and here is my output for cout << Array[2];

[OutputArray2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNRU1.png)

Comment: You missed to reset the read pointer for the file to the start after the 1st. loop. Also you don't need to know the number of lines in advance, just use `std::getline()` and `std::istringstream` to extract the values as needed.

Comment: After the first loop, `pbin` still has `eof` flag set. All read operations fail. In fact, I think `if(pbin!=NULL)` check is false, so the code doesn't even get as far as calling your `operator>>`

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: Also never post images of text here please. You can easily copy your terminal outputs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How can i reset the read pointer can you please be more spesific? Thanks for the information about istringstream! i didn't know that =)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik@IgorTandetnik hey. how can i set the !=eof? I tried to do !=EOF but it didnt work.

Comment: @user023835 Well, in your case it would be `pin.clear();` before `pi.seekg(0);`. But as mentione you don't need the 1st loop at all, if you read the file. line by line.

Comment: @user023835 Here's a solution for a problem very similar to yours n(just with another complication you don't have here): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-record-struct-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: My apologies for forgetting that older compilers required you to manually clear the EOF flag when you rewound the file with `seekg` in my previous answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem results from the wrong used algorithm and wrongly placed statements.

So, let's look what is going on in the below:

```
long linecount;
for(linecount=0;getline(pbin,line);linecount++)
    ;
contact* myArray = new contact[linecount];
pbin.seekg(0);
if(pbin.is_open()){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<linecount;i++){
        if(pbin!=NULL) {
            while(pbin>>myArray[i]);
        }
    }
    pbin.close();
```

You want to count the lines. So you read all lines until the `eof`state is set. But, additionally, also the `fail` bit will be set. See also [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

If you use your debugger, you will find a 3 in `_Mystate`.

[image: After all std::getline]

Then you perform a `seekg`. This will reset the `eof` bit but keep the `fail` bit. The dubugger shows then

[image: After seekg]

You can see that the `fail` bit is still set.

So, and this will now lead to the main problem. If your write `if(pbin!=NULL)` which is definitely wrong (on my machine is does not even compile), or if you better write `if(pbin)` the fail bit will still be set. And because the `bool` and the `!` operator for streams is overwritten (please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)) the result of the `if` and `while` will be false and your `pbin>>myArray[i]` will never be executed.

So, a `pbin.clear()` would help.

But, although your class definition is already very good, with inserter and extractor overwritten, you do not use the full C++ power for reading the data.

One basic recommendation would be to never use raw pointers for owned memory. And best also not `new`. Use dedicated containers for your purpose. E.g. a `std::vector`. The you can use the `std::vector`s constructor [no 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) together with a `std::istream_iterator`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). The range based constructor for the `std::vector` will copy data from a given range, denoted by the begin and end iterator. And if you use the `std::istream_iterator`, it will call your overwritten extractor operator, until all data are read.

So your main shrinks to:

```
int main() {

    // Open source file and check, if it could be opened
    if (ifstream pbin("r:\\phoneData2.txt");pbin) {

        // Read complete source file
        std::vector data(std::istream_iterator<contact>(pbin), {});

        // Show data on console
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<contact>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This looks by far compacter and is easier to read. We start with an [if-statement with initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). The initializer parts defines the variable and the constructor will open the file for us. In the condition part, we simple write `pbin`. And, as explained above, its `bool` operator will be called, to check if everything was ok.

Please note:

1. We do not need a `close` statement, because the destructor of the
   `std::ifstream` will close the file for us.
2. The outer namespace will not be polluted with the variable name `pbin`. That is one of the reasons, why `if`statement with initializer should be used.

We alread descibed the `std::vector` with its range constructor. SO reading the complete file is simple done by the very simple statement

```
std::vector data(std::istream_iterator<contact>(pbin), {});
```

Please note:

1. We do not define the type of the `std::vector`. This will be automatically deduced by the compiler through [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)
2. We use the default initialzer `{}` for the end iterator, as can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator) in constructor number 1.

---

The whole program could then be rewritten to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class contact {
private:

    int listno;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string phonenumber;

public:
    contact() {
        this->name = "Unknown";
        this->surname = "Unknown";
        this->phonenumber = "Unknown";
        this->listno = 0;
    }
    contact(string name, string surname, string phonenumber) {
        this->name = name;
        this->surname = surname;
        this->phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }
    contact(int listno, string name, string surname, string phonenumber) {

        this->name = name;
        this->surname = surname;
        this->listno = listno;
        this->phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const contact& con) {
        out << con.listno << '\t' << con.name << '\t' << con.surname << '\t' << con.phonenumber;
        return out;
    }

    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, contact& con) {
        in >> con.listno >> con.name >> con.surname >> con.phonenumber;
        return in;
    }
};

int main() {

    // Open source file and check, if it could be opened
    if (ifstream pbin("r:\\phoneData2.txt");pbin) {

        // Read complete source file
        std::vector data(std::istream_iterator<contact>(pbin), {});

        // Show data on console
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<contact>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```